# Declare a type that allows all parts of all levels of another type

Tags: typescript

I have a function that returns any value of an object by a list of keys.
Example:

Given this interface

```
interface Test {
  test1: string;
  test2: {
    test2Nested: {
      something: string;
      somethingElse: string;
    };
  };
}
```

I have an object

```
const test: Test = {
  test1: "",
  test2: {
    test2Nested: {
      something: "",
      somethingElse: "",
    },
  },
}
```

```
function getByPath<ObjectType, ReturnType) (obj: ObjectType, ...keys: string[]): ReturnType {
   return keys.reduce(
      (result: any, key: string) => result[key],
      obj
    );
}
```

`getByPath(test, 'test2', 'test2Nested')`  will return

```
{
   something: "",
   somethingElse: "",
}
```

The question is: how can I make this function type safe especially the return type, to only contain valid partial and possibly nested values? Is this even possible?

Please check [this snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDLKRYCMAXMllKAOYDcBRmYATBfoYcawHLMQATdo06UA9gFsIYABa0KVWg1GEMk6XJA0AogBsMEBWGpblnAL5nLec3jsIxILEywV0zgLy5G3csgBE-gA0Psxs3qLcLHxYgsIq4lKy8gHBIpxqSZo6+oapIaLmBchFNnZ4MACuIAhgwI7INNIAQgCeAApwsgA8APIARgBWELWorQAOEAUAStKVUCBjk8gQAB6QIAIYyJ1QdXC6fUMjYEsQAHyEAPRXlDJilboCyP0o43B7wAdEExB4lwAKMRDCgDYajX5BZAAOlhAGsIK0MEYTDQANoAXQAlBRZmB5otfhFRFA5gtkAikdDSQJKkgAelCADSRhHmAKHAQK0oTc7g8ni83h99rofpNGRTESjaFjkB5Liy2WjKRjiqJgYN0liGLY8A4nGJdBBoboxDQAU0wG1OrIAdwoQByKIOx1RGKQAQOrFY+yOZwYe6PATNCAANQOwCEO2FX0O7jAly8HBUmQ0KUCaoy6mSWj0BgogRsQA) for an example

Comment: This would be a better example if it had real identifier names in it.  Foo Bar examples seldom establish enough context to provide adequate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it in several steps.

```js
// Simple union type for primitives
type Primitives = string | number | symbol;
```

Our type for `keys` should allow props in strict order and it should be an array (because of `rest` operator).
I think the best here is to create a union type of all possible arguments.

Let's do it.

```js
type NestedKeys<T, Cache extends Array<Primitives> = []> = T extends Primitives ? Cache : {
    [P in keyof T]: [...Cache, P] | NestedKeys<T[P], [...Cache, P]>
}[keyof T]

// ["test1"] | ["test2"] | ["test2", "test2Nested"] | ["test2", "test2Nested", "something"] | ["test2", "test2Nested", "somethingElse"] | ["test2", "test2Nested", "test3Nestend"] .....
```

Now, we should write a type for our reducer logic.

```js
type Elem = string;

type Predicate<Result extends Record<string, any>, T extends Elem> = T extends keyof Result ? Result[T] : never

type Reducer<
    Keys extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>,
    Accumulator extends Record<string, any> = {}
    > = Keys extends []
    ? Accumulator
    : Keys extends [infer H]
    ? H extends Elem
    ? Predicate<Accumulator, H>
    : never
    : Keys extends readonly [infer H, ...infer Tail]
    ? Tail extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>
    ? H extends Elem
    ? Reducer<Tail, Predicate<Accumulator, H>>
    : never
    : never
    : never;
```

This type is doing almost exactly what You did in reducer. Why almost? Because it is recursive type.
I gave same names for variables, so it will be much easier to understand what happens here.
More examples You can find [here](https://catchts.com/tuples#reduce), in my blog.

After we have created all our types,  we can implement the function with tests:

```js
const getByPath = <Obj, Keys extends NestedKeys<Obj> & string[]>(obj: Obj, ...keys: Keys): Reducer<Keys, Obj> =>
    keys.reduce((acc, elem) => acc[elem], obj as any)


getByPath(test, 'test1') // ok
getByPath(test, 'test1', 'test2Nested') // expected error
getByPath(test, 'test2') // ok
const result = getByPath(test, 'test2', 'test2Nested') // ok -> {  something: string;  somethingElse: string; test3Nestend: { end: string;  }; }
const result3 = getByPath(test, 'test2', 'test2Nested', 'test3Nestend') // ok -> {end: stirng}
getByPath(test, 'test2', 'test2Nested', 'test3Nestend', 'test2Nested') // expeted error
const result2=getByPath(test, 'test2', 'test2Nested', 'test3Nestend', 'end') // ok -> string
getByPath(test, 'test2', 'test2Nested', 'test3Nestend', 'end', 'test2') // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwLABQyxykWAjAFzJZSgDmA3ISaZmAEzX5GslmcAcuwgATbiz5SMAewC2EMAAsG1Wg2a8prWQuUMAogBsMENWDogmk7f3YBmYVgghxuG7b4u36qx9sAvv4kAZqsoYRBBIRgAJ4ADigACnRywGDAAG6YyAC8NBYMyAA%20yCAArnIARtAlNLHVMkaaMQkoTpCiANIQsRgAPKgANMgAwohKKBAAHpCuGMgAglBQcLH9KcBpGdkYAHx5yADaALoH%20ajIM3OiC5vbWTkA-GMTKBJax0nIoMgA1r0ZDA0CdqEcAHSQ8YISYjJInOodMQ9PqDI7wkYQqFvOFnSJHAGxIEgwiEBAyEBYNhYajoKn5HisARUZAAIlZQw8Ai47k%20TPYHCRbkZnmIukUKis1HZnL52nF%20isxlM0o5wSkAkcIlcH1FUm81AA5N5Deq%20FFArLwrKoq1EshjBA5IdfNZogQ4vaUmJgAg4JB%20gAlTDlIzYa7eBbB8lQUT9V0jOAgWJ7EaXCPzB1GJ3nNBXWaR-6A4HBjCh7AvUvlo6oBHUEAQbJQUketrIYOicpIKD9DwohYZ27tiBwUQUoyxZardaOuSpjyLBAISqh-0yKD5m5RiAxuMJ5BJlOHHAWki5-ubwunDwvRfLuSrsDrjzUC%20DhZHUAwWoACRON%20QH9L0zWcAO9URfX9CB%20jvFcjDXKARh-PYXzKRtoFQt8C0zKARzHEAJ2OL9fxGSFwWIjdUDgYAjH-T4XiomjgKHYNR3HScVjWfpZxQ%20jAOYhZQL4jsu2gQZqKMOFcIgv0A1gh94KfRDAL2XjWHrdDm0%20DSm1Qhsmxad1yUpbB6EUAAhWIkn9JRDn6AB5KoACsRiwrdkCFfsHOcg4ADICksehTj2AAKGRnOoRyXOQMjCQwV9egwABKagRO7fp%20xGKLzjUkg4vBaTRJCkLEAQEYIGzOQkryA5SqOCqnROEZwqcg8FkPJKW0IMywEs6zlBCgQRkNZlDWqgB6cbkBkP5uosqybMG9hhtGlaBSFMbkEm-NEgQTorhWZ8CB6vrFqG5ARoFTbtpmskKSpXCyzDQ4ToWgbzsurAOENNavo2iappm5AAFoDhwMV5AlVQAo0CG9ElehlTMGGrEYakwC1ZwdVwK5sddNHkFCQm7pM5BHvLewXvm-qlCWrBfs4H6Lu5DaGcxm5rsBv4QbBg0CmAKArCiV6abpsAGe%20iXWeZhwkVcJnPqEERRE5nbFDEA6oCO4yHpDMMOFyEWzuWmWvoVlnlfN2XtRV4aTQB6budBlH6Dm3q3tpj7uStv7LbZuXbYuk0JdVmZdv26AtagIA)

[More exaplanation You can find in my blog](https://catchts.com/deep-pick)

**DOT NOTATION**

```js
type Foo = {
    user: {
        description: {
            name: string;
            surname: string;
        }
    }
}

declare var foo: Foo;

type Primitives = string | number | symbol;

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Elem = string;

type Acc = Record<string, any>

// (acc, elem) => hasProperty(acc, elem) ? acc[elem] : acc
type Predicate<Accumulator extends Acc, El extends Elem> =
    El extends keyof Accumulator ? Accumulator[El] : Accumulator

type Reducer<
    Keys extends Elem,
    Accumulator extends Acc = {}
    > =
    Keys extends `${infer Prop}.${infer Rest}`
    ? Reducer<Rest, Predicate<Accumulator, Prop>>
    : Keys extends `${infer Last}`
    ? Predicate<Accumulator, Last>
    : never


const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends Primitives>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
    : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, any> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

type KeysUnion<T, Cache extends string = ''> =
    T extends Primitives ? Cache : {
        [P in keyof T]:
        P extends string
        ? Cache extends ''
        ? KeysUnion<T[P], `${P}`>
        : Cache | KeysUnion<T[P], `${Cache}.${P}`>
        : never
    }[keyof T]

type O = KeysUnion<Foo>

type ValuesUnion<T, Cache = T> =
    T extends Primitives ? T : Values<{
        [P in keyof T]:
        | Cache | T[P]
        | ValuesUnion<T[P], Cache | T[P]>
    }>

declare function deepPickFinal<Obj, Keys extends KeysUnion<Obj>>
    (obj: ValuesUnion<Obj>, keys: Keys): Reducer<Keys, Obj>


/**
 * Ok
 */
const result = deepPickFinal(foo, 'user') // ok
const result2 = deepPickFinal(foo, 'user.description') // ok
const result3 = deepPickFinal(foo, 'user.description.name') // ok
const result4 = deepPickFinal(foo, 'user.description.surname') // ok

/**
 * Expected errors
 */
const result5 = deepPickFinal(foo, 'surname')
const result6 = deepPickFinal(foo, 'description')
const result7 = deepPickFinal(foo)
```