# Typescript recursive type of object to string

Tags: typescript, recursive-type

Lets say i have this object (it came from a json)

```
    const obj = {
      a: '1',
      b: '1',
      c: {
        d: '2',
        e: '2',
        f: {
          g: '3',
          h: {
            i: '4',
          },
        },
      },
    };
```

i want to declare a type of string that will autocomplete the nested object.
i managed to accomplish something like that but it is far from perfect:

```
type RecuresiveKeyOf<TObj> = {
  [TKey in keyof TObj & string]: {
    [TKey1 in keyof TObj[TKey] & string]: `${TKey}.${TKey1}`;
  }[keyof TObj[TKey] & string];
}[keyof TObj & string];
```

[now, when i try to use it i get this autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2jM9.png).
[but i also get unnecessary fields of string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESQ05.png)

for conclusion i want it to be able to auto complete for me the nested object as a string.
note that the amount of levels of the nested object is unknown.

Comment: See [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0AAxW) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668055/eliminate-nevers-to-make-union-possible/68672512?noredirect=1#comment121362429_68672512) and [my article](https://catchts.com/deep-pick)

Comment: Please see the `Leaves<T>` type in the answer to the linked question.  For your code it looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpLLam), producing the type `"a" | "b" | "c.d" | "c.e" | "c.f.g" | "c.f.h.i"`.