# Infer dot notation of nested property

Tags: typescript

I want to achieve type safety on the `deps` array below. So the only allowed strings are dot notation of `${moduleX}.${moduleX service}`

```
// Modules each have a factory function that can return a services object (async)
createModules({
  data: {
    factory: () => Promise.resolve(() => {
      return {
        services: {
          createResource: () => {}
        },
      };
    })
  },
  dependentModule: {
    deps: ['data.createResource'], // <!-- should allow this
    factory: () => Promise.resolve(() => ({}))
  },
  incorrectConfig: {
    deps: ['data.serviceDoesNotExist'], // <-- should error here
    factory: () => Promise.resolve(() => ({}))
  }
});

function createModules<M>(config: Config<M>) {}

export type Config<M> = {
  [K in keyof M]: ModuleConfig<M>
}

export type Config<M> = {
  [K in keyof M]: {
    deps?: (`${keyof M & string}.${keyof (Awaited<M[keyof M]['factory']>['services']) & string}`)[]
    factory: () => Promise<(...args: any) => { services?: { [key: string]: any } }>
  }
}
```

As I have it now, `data.serviceDoesNotExist` is allowed because it's just being inferred as a `string`:

```
deps?: (`data.${string}` | `dependentModule.${string}` | `incorrectConfig.${string}`)[] | undefined
```

How can I get the actual property name as the inference here?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFkHsBMFcBsCmBnUiCGBjAFqb6A3RUdUAMywBdIAnAT3NgDtNKBLSJ0S-S0TdFxqJKsGl1LJENAm0wpQkAEYArRK1AAKdMjosAlAFgAUJmHpKiKHCTJNAbxOhQ0C+gBcoR8efOKrWjpPTX1QAF4APlAABRpIAFs2KQA6YWRIeCJNEPCo719fYVFxLycC3ykZORRPfPKCswxLACUUSDF5YNDIrwBfMvregBoB316AblHeox9QYbLoRAAHRCZFpkprBERa0cWl5E8AbQByV0p0ZMaLRFb0jsQTgF0h0BBQAB4AQgBaH9BkNh2vBoCR4PBIAB3bjYJKjfzUehdXIxOKJFJpDJZHI9BzTGbOeazNgsWjCVgAYU4ZDYAHNdrNnPtDqBTudLpVZPIACKQFAAOUglAAogAPJKUZ6vd4fP4AoEIUHSOI0PDSRDwqiBZE9WIJJKIVJtTKIbLdKJ4-QEuYmaaTYwmd4ASVAkMEfGoJBwbEQRG4dBWAPQZBEDE4MOIAANmZGSDQaOgGOglJAiMlQABlSARxRMeBJ8FQxCg5CUGgk2modDCFxC0BMIUWDhcSBkUCRgAk9niMG2AA1eskuz2bIg+wDpFzEL1IyYTGRmKxm-xzJYtrYPuAIppMNS6Z4qUwabTNxFQvZ+g7jIhRUtaB6A8RD8fT+FSrMjgBpUAk0AAa0QOhWwgJ4GQKZkAH5gk7ewAKAttwFAAAyAEywrQcuzg4DNAAQTdNhLGgTcjiwhCnlOBFAmeCJTk5apkGeUIUNLcsmFpGd9COJ5NQCJEtHNVF9SkD5NGSMTq0rTxBDoAT7AnKp5GQKCvFZODPBYitQJIJgGF6OYIjKS9eiAA)

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668055/eliminate-nevers-to-make-union-possible/68672512?noredirect=1#comment121362429_68672512) you can find a way to infer allowed properties of an object with dot notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a probably multiple solutions to solve this. Here is my way.

I would use two generic types `M` and `S` to store the module strings and service strings respectively.

```
function createModules<
  M extends string, 
  S extends string
>(config: Config<M, S>) {}
```

The `Config` type will then be a `Record` where the possible keys are `M` and the values are a `ModuleConfig`. We will pass both `M` and `S` to the `ModuleConfig`.

```
export type Config<
  M extends string, 
  S extends string
> = Record<M, ModuleConfig<M, S>>
```

In the `ModuleConfig`, we can infer `S` as the keys of the `services` object.

```
export type ModuleConfig<
  M extends string, 
  S extends string,
> = {
  deps?: /* ... */
  factory: () => Promise<(...args: any) => { services?: Record<S, any> }>
};
```

For the `deps` property it gets more technical. We have a bit of a chicken-egg problem going on here. If we just use `M` and `S` in the template string literal, TypeScript will actual prefer to use the contents of the passed strings to infer `M` and `S` instead of the keys of the objects. Which is totally correct but not what we want to happen since this would restrict the keys of the objects to whatever strings you put in the arrays and not the other way around.

I created a `Copy` utility type to prevent this.

```
type Copy<S extends string> = S extends infer U extends string ? U : never

export type ModuleConfig<
  M extends string, 
  S extends string,
> = {
  deps?: (`${Copy<M>}.${Copy<S>}`)[]
  factory: () => Promise<(...args: any) => { services?: Record<S, any> }>
};
```

This should do the trick.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=42&ssc=3&pln=34&pc=1#code/PTAEFkHsBMFcBsCmBnUiCGBjAFqb6A3RUdUAMywBdIAnAT3NgDtNKBLSJ0S-S0TdFxqJKsGl1LJENAm0wpQkAEYArRK1AAKdMjosAlAFgAUJmHpKiKHCTJNAbxOhQ0C%20gBcoR8efOKrWjpPTX1QAF4APlAABRpIAFs2KQA6YWRIeCJNEPCo719fYVFxLycC3ykZORRPfPKCswxLACUUSDF5YNDIrwBfMvregBoB316AblHeox9QYbLoRAAHRCZFpkprBERa0cWl5E8AbQAiV0p0ZMaLRFb0jsQTgF0h0BBQAB4AQgBaH9BkNh2vBoCR4PBIAB3bjYJIjWZ%20KiBLq5GJxRIpNIZLI5HoOaYzZzzWZsFi0YSsADCnDIbAA5rsES5lodQEcAOTnS6VWTyAAikBQADlIJQAKIADySlHZLzeYA%20fwBQIQoOkcRoeGkiFG-mo9BRPViCSSiFSbUyiGy3Si%20P0hLmJmmk2MJneAElQJDBHxqCQcGxEERuHQVgD0GQRAxODDiAADfbIOMkGg0dAMdBKSBEZKgADKkFjiiY8Az4KhiFByEoNFJdNQ6GELlFoCYoosHC4kDIoDjABJ7PEYNsABq9ZIDoc2RAjgHSXmIXpxkwmMjMVid-jmSxbWwfMrgNASyxrVDV2tMOmvMp5o8n6Bnmt1kwRTSYGn0zzUpi0ukfcCvHmEShPY-SusYiASkstC%20qGxDfr%20%206zIekH3o%20F5XqAN53qsD4Ak%20l4vuEoCtO%20NDQP%20ry7ogCH0pR%20YRBEK7GJQcGgNSSx0B8t6obh6F1lEYT5jhp6gKSkaagAqiJeHnnWoAAPygNJnhMEG0jMZB0E0LBYbUbRf4HjJ-GXtesw8cefH4Rh8KCaUsyJgpwT9vYHFceAETjgObncZ5cb6EcTxlHqyJaDaaImlIHyaMksWNvWniCHQ4X2HOVTyMgTkkeotAUXmrxJVEvRMcYExAA)

---

**Edit:**

Here is a different solution which adresses the issues mentioned in the comments.

```
type Factory = () => Promise<(...args: any) => { services?: Record<string, any> }>

type ExtractServiceKeys<T extends Factory> = 
  keyof ReturnType<Awaited<ReturnType<T>>>["services"] & string

function createModules<
  T extends Record<string, {
    deps?: ({ 
      [K in keyof T]: `${K & string}.${ExtractServiceKeys<T[K]["factory"]>}`
    }[keyof T])[],
    factory: Factory
  }>,
>(config: T) {}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFkHsBMFcBsCmBnUiCGBjAFqb6A3RUdUAMywBdIAnAT3NgDtNKBLSJ0S-S0TdFxqJKsGl1LJENAm0wpQkAEYArRK1AAKdMjosAlAFgAUJmHpKiKHCTJNAbxOhQ0C%20gBcoR8efOKrWjpPTX1QAF4APlAABRpIAFs2KQA6YWRIeCJNEPCo719fYVFxLycC3ykZORRPfPKCswxLACUUSDF5YNDIrwBfMvregBoB316AblHeox9QYbLoRAAHRCZFpkprBERa0cWl5E8AbQAiV0p0ZMaLRFb0jsQTgF0h0BBQAB4AQgBaH9BkNh2vBoCR4PBIAB3bjYJIjWZ%20KiBLq5GJxRIpNIZLI5HoOaYzZzzWZsFi0YSsADCnDIbAA5rsES5lodQEcAOTnS6VWTyAAikBQADlIJQAKIADySlHZLzeYA%20fwBQIQoOkcRoeGkiFG-mo9BRPViCSSiFSbUyiGy3Tyo2cRTEXDq9R51VZzvq-HMlgA8jxpHd2jROlobX07WN4YNJkzpmV%20sZpjGTCZKHQVqAAGJI%20jhUOo40YxAfTTJMvoGh01mCOhh%20wA6S8lAAfk8rUwtGgH2QlBopLprxrUV6ERTxjTGclvaoAGVG9UANKIOjID4AFTQEssa1Q2YC9CiYVAAGtl5AyKBWsUmGv08WAIKQ9BsSxdq%20O28rdcRH%20nV3yZBnlAAAyAFe37McyGYVgOC4a5LC2WwPjKDdEC3VZoFQdtO27cCmAHUomX2ZBWy0esIyOBdQFJE8zwvNcnk8AADAASewqNAns%203w3pkjYqcaFned5CXFd10op5Tj1QJngiXomKmI5Tzoc9QAY-QjheXUcyCLMdPjCJ4QiTQOyYWkGTU0J7F6IA)

Comment: Hi @TobiasS. , sorry, don't know how to reach you. I have published your example, regarding type literal substring in my article, see here https://catchts.com/transformation-utils#substring

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine - nice ;D

Comment: This is definitely a solution, but what I'm after is something where the generic types `M` is an object type, because I need to assert its shape too, e.g. deps, and factory (amongst other things that I've left out due to brevity).

Comment: @AndyJessop - Can you share an example where the solution does not work for you? What do you mean by "assert its shape too"? It would be helpful if you chould share a Playground.

Comment: The problem is that in the above example, `'incorrectConfig.createResource'` is a valid value for a `deps` entry, but that service doesn't exist on the `incorrectConfig` module.