# How to specify types for nested "maybes" in generated query types?

Tags: typescript, graphql, typescript-typings, react-typescript, graphql-codegen

I use Graphql codegen to generate types from our schema. I need access to nested types and have commonly used the following method:

```
 type Iresponse = myType[level1][level2]
```

This works great when there are no Maybes, meaning a possibility of it being null. When types are defined as "maybe" I cannot use it and it it throws an error.

Does anyone have a practical solution to specify these nested types? I dont wanna wrap every step in a number of nonNullable generics...

Thank you in advance !

Comment: do you have only two level of nested props? Because we can end up with some crazy typings

Answer (score 3):

Arbitrary depth:

```
type Get<T, X> = X extends keyof T ? T[X] : never
type Path<T, P extends any[]> = P extends [infer X, ...infer Y] ? Path<Get<NonNullable<T>, X>, Y> : T

type Iresponse = Path<myType, ["level1", "level2", "response"]>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4CgUEsB2NhQGYCGAxsHAGIQSIpy1wA2wAbsPQIwBc1dPcA7gAsCOFlC4FMATwA0NXrUYt6AJgD8XBHPk8IAay4woAV2CztvKMADOkTFeAat53jhAwuVw1gDmT53VwoaHVuf2dA6ABhCAATBzhMIwBbACNcPzCeSwIrCEwPL0xfTJ5UTLKw%200w4sVCSuGh0bywCqB8M%20QrOp1RUFAB6frgAQRgcJLB4AGI2FBhJMFIAEWBgMAAlYABHI3RLGIAeABUAPjgAXkQ4AG0AaTgsOF1gSQg8OCOAXQBaEKO4UA4apWRBIOCqOArNabHZ7YCHI53T5nLiI26fOCoeaLOCbGxsC6Q1Ybba7fYHCgQE7XABEilYbBpn1p9JUTNplhseXsTIGQwACkEUowklw8WAAHQRKAPKyYADk8Agk3QeQI9DQgxGY2AE2myj5cAAAjArN8mphoMAUHEiPQCJYGMB4JywISABSJej0OA5ciUACUEtZbGDzFYaglru5wAAhHMFqRxcpCdjgG84K7DQBlSTYAggWVwTxGMDoGKaoajcaTOBTADMCZxAHFncdpHAABpnS6dgFuYDAp4vDP-CGIzsYriYcNQJukfnCATtuD8-tAmIgiSSa7IwlrwGDzc3LB4XBdjsSq%20n88ATQxEMXMGXrZgBwAcnl30ZvQRhcBjhODtuw7W8UQ%20edcWsMB633JcKUoDsWXDdgaQ7OkUOUNC4BpaM7GAJkTkg8V6xSODnwQiAkIwpRGXQ1ksPQvCeXQ6VCMNQVnXmOBvEoGIgA)

Comment: Pretty interesting example. I think you need to handle also this case:`type Resp3b = Path<Foo, ["level1", "l", "response", "error"]>` when array may contain wrong props. You can also consider computing the permutation of all allowed props like  `KeysUnion` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126879/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object-with-related-type

Comment: Indeed, it does not check that the path is valid, nor does it provide autocompletion.

Comment: You can event try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126879/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object-with-related-type . See last example

Answer (score 2):

You can use built in [NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) util

```js
type MyType = {
    foo: {
        bar: [1, 2, 4] | null
    } | null
}


type GetNullable<T, Prop extends keyof NonNullable<T>> = NonNullable<T>[Prop]

// [1, 2, 4] | null
type NestedData = GetNullable<MyType['foo'], 'bar'>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8CwAoKuoDMB7QgLnWz0qgCMBDAJzIG0BGAGigCYOAWAXSgAfKADsArgBsJFPAF8hoydKyzsarKEhQA4hGAA5JbWoSIAHngcACvUJgoEAB7AIIgCYBnKAGsIIQvhQ%20oQihlLGphYAfFFQqMGhRibm8FFMNnZ86gD02VCsHNxQ-AriUtia0PoQHi5uACK0wLRxOnphEhHmcIiQTADkRIT9fBz9dPT9UdhAA)

OR

```js
type Truthy<T> = NonNullable<T>

type GetData = Truthy<Truthy<MyType['foo']>>['bar']
```

If you need more sophisticated util, please see this [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwjpAhgYwNYHsBuBTAJwDMAbbAdwDp1sBbYARwFd8UBLbAOzmADYAHH0EAGAKxjg%20UuzrsuqSPgC0XfAUJxlkbMrqpMK5l05dlMbHDjsARqXz8hAdgBMYgIwuA-F2yF8ACbs-uiQALzuAMS0dHT4XJCe7gDMfC4ALC4AnAD6gnyuHi4AsABQIBDQ8EjA6IroUHA09MAB%20Pgw5uxYZZAAnjD4oADKkITMocz%20oGGgAN5loEugqISECPOLy9sBiqgbC6Xbx8v4dDD9ACrMMPYbANoAugA0Wyfbq4SofQcrAOb4DZcZh0GxEUAAXyeb2OENAAB9QMDSKQYRCyujSr0BkMAKL2OgzUAoQjyP4AbjK2MGoAAaqhSKw4AAeS4APiJl3uhj62GIoEujyppX6NIAknAAHLqIisjmze6C0D4AAeSi4ATgoHuag0j1AXlAY1YoA2xAZcHwlKxNtFQwAguh0ESAEr4WiEALMklk54rLh9NnCu2gN0BCZEADCDNINgwmGZjvQIOYpEUfmVavimtASb9%20Mz6pz%20LO8phBdVRa1PL5uadKbTOkIBrryboqfThHu%20P1GyTDc7wZxocCEcIzJhAGl8H0tZXs1qS3RXkdlv3242M-ONVqk0S5pjtmXV0tp7PCwvQAADAAkc3kxHBAAVCNgYBCqHeH%20C3SgIVeYUNMMx2ZX9ID9YD0CjGM4ywRN6w3Ts-RfN82SDE9TVAM85yzHdry-LhH2bAAZVA-wAjCgNHKDCGjFFYITdcOybP1SJQdDtiBGVCCHcU4GuW58DlGYYQACkuC88PtNZvmZVAAw5LwYW2cT7gAcnsLg-kgcA1P1bcc2BUEiGU95DVEoywWbAytS5DT4m03ShQw95jkNc1SEtUzXKWDZjXwABKbzjj88ZAuCs0LXC21hwlXFziuG57FZSSc2kr4%20jkhT5QFdTNMcvTUq1EQW38zCPK8mKaTo2N41ZP1owaIYbOJMZfVAYiZVIIqkRBKynhy%20lGTYZlDm2e4n1AeRQBrflBQQMTJpan0tOC8zGvAZrcJzNS1OC7ZDWwgBVExuFZCaXnwuYn3-P17ioB7OoIUg-XcR4OJ83yOq6vKHJ0wqWvcfblkOmc4BO0xzqfS7bzmDb8A-O8bqvO6HqoJ7pFe97ga%20%20GESwsGIbOrlob9WH4cR67bu1NGMZe0A3o%20k4gpc5YuI0FmIXQ6khmO06uAnDDLhXbY8eWtqtKJXaReWOmessogniJaEMOPFSJJalDBkIfozzW0B4Yi0BxJ69LZPkwMcZbUSJQE5L2R6-yrYO424oSvo7aEh2Wqd1nPpdvHET5yGlzJu8Kc-OZlHcf8mf9k4Nhqhj6oNjBNtYrq2RZ%20POONjXtt3GTMu-ZslzjnOQdACVpQ0Zky8dsLnbM1Omvx4OztDq6I7vaPqfux6uqx8uK8wwOCdnImBc78m04RyOFcIPvacHhnsb9nP2aIALs-9xOYLq4WW-T77nuHpYd-P3i8RVRk2gACXYP5wDp4TZnzqtWtJSXDQkzeeJtCoAAiT4VBdhoEAfjYBaxQF7CoGcC4Hskr4AgYiKBhAYFoDge7T2VBo4oNAGgjBqAqCfG%20Pgq8ICwHENIX0eefUiD-nxhQ6BVCSFFzocZReJCAQURDJcNgkAiS4hvswe%20j9n5dWZO3AWoxxiTH8GhK%20Bt6AwGYEoZkT5FDgB6itP4fpZETEgFMfAOUDHyKGAAMk2BhCar4YBTS4KATROlHgbEgrKLW%20jjTmPQpiHmI44CpkEbMSMKi1FewEV4uRRiFFKIAOL4EgL%20IJrpqKyjUpQvYak-RjWWJ8A4wUqEPHcH6Fwfpkj6kRMiVEGFMRc2FEAA) last row and related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126879/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object-with-related-type)

```js
type Structure = {
    user: {
        tuple: [42],
        emptyTuple: [],
        array: { age: number }[]|null
    }
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type IsNever<T> = [T] extends [never] ? true : false;

type IsTuple<T> =
    (T extends Array<any> ?
        (T['length'] extends number
            ? (number extends T['length']
                ? false
                : true)
            : true)
        : false)

type IsEmptyTuple<T extends Array<any>> = T['length'] extends 0 ? true : false

type HandleDot<
    Cache extends string,
    Prop extends string | number
    > =
    Cache extends ''
    ? `${Prop}`
    : `${Cache}.${Prop}`

type HandleObject<Obj, Cache extends string> = {
    [Prop in keyof Obj]:
    | HandleDot<Cache, Prop & string>
    | Path<Obj[Prop], HandleDot<Cache, Prop & string>>
}[keyof Obj]

type Path<Obj, Cache extends string = ''> =
    (Obj extends PropertyKey
        ? Cache
        : (Obj extends Array<unknown>
            ? (IsTuple<Obj> extends true
                ? (IsEmptyTuple<Obj> extends true
                    ? Path<PropertyKey, HandleDot<Cache, -1>>
                    : HandleObject<Obj, Cache>)
                : Path<Obj[number], HandleDot<Cache, number>>)
            : HandleObject<Obj, Cache>)
    )

type WithDot<T extends string> = T extends `${string}.${string}` ? T : never


type Acc = Record<string, any>

type ReducerCallback<Accumulator extends Acc, El extends string> =
    El extends keyof Accumulator ? Accumulator[El] : El extends '-1' ? never : Accumulator

type Reducer<
    Keys extends string,
    Accumulator extends Acc = {}
    > =
    Keys extends `${infer Prop}.${infer Rest}`
    ? Reducer<Rest, ReducerCallback<Accumulator, Prop>>
    : Keys extends `${infer Last}`
    ? ReducerCallback<Accumulator, Last>
    : never


type BlackMagic<T> = T & {
    [Prop in WithDot<Extract<Path<Structure>, string>>]: Reducer<Prop, T>
}

type Result = Reducer<'user.array', Structure>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBXAxsR9oF4oG8CwAUFMVIgM4TwBcuhJ9UaYANhDQNoAsATALoA0dBsQgBbMKAAqiFmyjsBQ4QEN48ZSBo4oygOZyAdolEAjSlAC%20CgD5HmzJZcIXChUJCgA1Zc0QQyADySAHxQ2JLsANYQIAD2AGZQkryuBO7QAJJkAHIQAG6UQaHY7MlQEAAewBAGACZk8gb5lLxQAPyMSNA08T4UANyp6VBZ0rJFYY4AFJLlVTX1UACCahoBygYgoW2O9DPsAOSsBrrAABYHrZXVdQ1GppS7wu1QU-dm8HM3ixFHNacXFJEZ4gjq9ZgUJ4g4g0BB%20ACUUIYsK6iOBwh6fQgaLc4EyZAAouIpDJWEEvgsGit1CB1ptgsUkodjgDLhTblAAAwvOHdKDgyEEXEeAASG1qrAAIrFgAFHABhZTIM7Qa6UqBkBAASxOgnRUAACvBYmB2YtNfAdbooNYoO9HvrigqlSqzQ0DgdHB0AAYAEhwRpNFm9jhofpwiuVEAsADp-YGwMGhnioGK6qwAPImABWEFQASz2f4UEjrrVHItVsZ%20H17ATUB1UGicUShd4VEctrTEog0tlpYgxfrADINdqTsFO4blOcCzm68awAJU%20KpTKAgOh4uoKPKxPJwQrM2ElA28mPAaZ2c50WSy7VfMK%20PrdgPU79VNC27DYvKKAANIxEiHQDkiNCfjm37UmsiAGJEBixAA7gYB7QiQHRTKMpIQDeoTlosvJIqCrxZESEggGMZKFnhj4EV0RFoS8l6zgmf4gIBIDFt2a79vexYALQAIwMgxaE0NxECFnmsqFsWA7BGijHItOs6Fuw9rwMuEl9hufF2sYHwMopjHiaukk5tJN5yfeCmODiaQpgA6lq5w6bM%20ENHuuiMu5tENOGXmxv6gXei8sw0E0BTwKkwrQEsyDIGEUAAEp5rE8C1AEXnFhsWzntAqW1CglCKvYJhKpEATxcgxiIMwM7pVBCXFgSzDfl5770K137Hok1W1fVwCNR0-WiHVDXwOwrWtDQ3UeVABxCQcLyReYNCjeNQ3RUKDkeIVxXwHK%20ocQ083ZY4G2DY183VUlOAuI6kzHTEp1%20VA4Y6vE5gJkFOCfeYqWakm%20odPtyCFIDwDFmDJU%20Mw5XIJVl0TVuJoifqNAnd%20H0GF9nwADLKEDIYgylEBFeD8ClfDFVVQlA0o1AhOaqhJARc0235VAABC9WIwAsnoWrIBM4Q7rQtb1o2zmueuBJVOo%20bMdecBIKg6AQMExYdcE7ZkxThQJsWITOFzgN1cASUw4dBzkJQMaqDSBzFqrKBoBgwRAA)

Comment: I will provide more explanation later. In the mean time you can take a look on my related article https://catchts.com/deep-pick

Comment: You might wonna try  these two answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126879/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object-with-related-type

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your answers, they were really helpful!

What I ended up doing is using "typescript-compatibility" with the graphql generator. It adds types and subtypes that may be null too.
Basically what it does is just wrap all the nested types in NonNullable types.