# How to write a function which represents an object lookup path

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, function, console.log

Write a function that takes a object and a string, which represents an object lookup path, for example "something1.something2". The function should return the value on the specific path.
Example:

```
const lookup = (obj, path) => {....}
const obj = { something1: { something2: "Mouse", something3: 'Cat' } };
const path = 'something1.something2'
console.log(lookup(obj, path));
```

Result:
'Mouse'

Comment: What does this have to do with java?

Comment: Please see https://catchts.com/deep-pick and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126879/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object-with-related-type#answer-69129328

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` and then reference the property dynamically using square brackets

```js
const lookup = (obj, path) => {
    const paths = path.split('.');
    return obj[paths[0]][paths[1]];
}

const obj = { something1: { something2: "Mouse", something3: 'Cat' } };
const path = 'something1.something2'

console.log(lookup(obj, path));
```