# Typing a Path<T> of react-hook-form in a recursive iteration

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-hook-form

This is a typescript question, i will try to explain as good as possible. Find a link to a typescript playground with an illustration of the problem at the bottom.

It is about `react-hook-form`, which has a type `Path<TFieldValues>` (see https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/274d8fb950f9944547921849fb6b3ee6e879e358/src/types/utils.ts#L86), which is a string identifier for a possible nested field in dot-notation (i.e. `path`, `path.subpath`, `path.subpath.subpath` etc.) for a given structure `TFieldValues`, which are the form values. Its hooks require this `Path<TFieldValues>` when specifying a `fieldName`, which is desired and nice.

But i have a problem deriving such a `Path<TFieldValues>` variable, when i have a structure definition which i recursively iterate. What i am doing is, to traverse a structure definition (that conforms to the `TFieldValues` structure) with information on the ui. Then i traverse it and generate the UI for that, using `useController`. However i cannot find a way to have a strongly typed `Path<TFieldValues>`. You can see in the complete example in the link below, the gist:

```
// Simplified from react-hook-form, we only care about fieldName typing
const useController = <TFieldValues extends Record<string, any>>(fieldName: Path<TFieldValues>) => {};

// Could be something arbitrary but a fixed structure is given
const myValues = {
    number: 1,
    string: 'string',
    sub: {
        number: 2,
        sub: {
            string: 'string',
        },
    },
};

// This schema will be recursively walked to generate a UI, it is strongly typed to conform to myValues but that would exceed this post
const schema = {
    number: 'Number Field',
    string: 'String Field',
    sub: {
        number: 'Sub Number Field',
        sub: {
            string: 'Sub Sub String Field',
        },
    },
};

// This walk function illustrates the problem, as i cannot determine how to derive a valid path when recursive iterating
const walk = (node: Record<string, any>, path?: Path<typeof myValues>) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(node);
    for (let key in keys) {
        if (typeof node[key] === 'string') {
            useController<typeof myValues>(path ? `${path}.${key}` : key);
            // Show UI etc...
        } else {
            walk(node[key], path ? `${path}.${key}` : key);
        }
    }
}

// would be called
walk(schema);
```

Here is the problem illustrated in the typescript playground:
[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-CSGEaFREelOl1uuRQTQuXx4OAAClJEGwCO2xgGdDkAEoLKBILAEET0KT7KkuWkMrTnhoCkVSuVEMk+NxmpyxrEEhsS7y6WJliwRXBJX2KMPOtS+OsrliS0MALSjBba+zkynUgBk9LEfAkMK612R5mHw5lnUu6in8WqI0PC6Ly4YyQxiCxHOqCsHh4oo-cNFh4Mhs-nQsyQpe81w3Rkd1Hfch2PMF4XiIYCRzaB4DRa1gAYDhF1SdDMPZKZll8ct2jyI0oA4ZIGS3f0vlqeogOLeJcI4fCgTtFELFII0aBNbBEFYwj6PfYcWUUBYAEYoSHKjJAWboZIkbopMPYR0wWYSP0aVkFgAJmUzT6TUgchwM8CtzkhSlJMo99IoGUpJlcxuJNMAi3iCB7UTYABnMq1MAwrCi2Sc54T4gT2Po+T03VUSoG6JzjXgYQnEcPYhKHWK5IAOVkVk-ICqyVM3WS4G6e1iqZZjCuHVS5HU6yKEy0r7XTOAcrxfLMOqzTarmAACjTTLMkqytalq5DgcrGU6jhuo-eyYIcglnPgOgZlsQoxDUdQoHonD-Lwgi7S7Z4yIohSaO+WNeACrKNGwYAbx1JiDpYo7hGqDN6jqSVHIsFa4AAdymNwGljGgIC4BZSOgc6Ksu6oYVcgZAOwkLPDC97Pu+4zDwBsFfAaAB5OQACtnBgdUCfByHgAzA9h24aA43UeAwW-X9hC+wbDw8ON0Z2LhOjBIZ6mIBp5Iq7puYaj81uADbnSgbbFGColQv4rHY2R+w4DFKUdZlTVJTBFUFjBenZZldJplQHmDOBhgXBpoWRaRos9cVA2iyNqVTdFOBzdOS3TJlGDSBlIA)

P.S: Please do not suggest using `as`, `any` or something like that. I know i could cast it to make it work. But i want strong typing.

**EDIT**

A little edit here, as i was doing some more research. I think the problem can be simplified for better understanding. The main point is appending a new key to `Path<X>` and still get a valid `Path<X>` in return. If we can solve that, typing the recursive iteration should not be the problem. This essentially can be expressed in a simple function

```
declare function appendToPath<T>(path: Path<T>, appendKey: ???): Path<T>;
```

I tried to improve that, and have at least validly typed function parameters that behave correctly:

```
// Helper to determine valid keys for a nested object value
type NestedObjectKey<
    T extends FieldPathValue<TFieldValues, TFieldPath>,
    TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
    TFieldPath extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>,
> = T extends Record<string, any> ? keyof T : never;

// Append
function appendToPath<
    TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
    TFieldPath extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>
>(path: TFieldPath, keyToAppend: NestedObjectKey<FieldPathValue<TFieldValues, TFieldPath>>): Path<TFieldValues> {
    return `${path}.${keyToAppend}`; // this still raises an error
}
```

So from a human standpoint this should be enough logically and works as far using the function and its function signature is concerned. However unfortunately TS cannot infer this information as a human can when assembling the path and i have not found a way to do so so far. Last resort would be a custom type assertion, but that would add unnecessary code.

Another way to look at it from a human standpoint is a `${Path<A>}.${Path<B>}` is still a `Path<A>` variable if `FieldValue<A, Path<A>> = B`. I don't know if that could be translated to a working typescript implementation

Comment: AFAIK, you are not allowed to call react hook inside `if condition`

Comment: I know. But this is unrelated. This is just an illustration. `useController` might not even be a hook. Maybe i could have chosen this better for the example.

Comment: This feels like a similar problem to typing "safe-get" operations: https://dev.to/tipsy_dev/advanced-typescript-reinventing-lodash-get-4fhe

Comment: well, thanks for your input. It provides a good explaination on the used types. However this is already implemented in the types provided by `react-hook-form` (and also the reason why you need specify the `Path<T>`). In the end the problem really is the recursive iteration and building the path dynamically within not the safe getting of it's value. In the end the iteration in this post using `.reduce` is typed as `(value as any)?.[key],`

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126879/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object-with-related-type#answer-69129328) you can find alternative implementation of Path util type

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental problem is that your `walk` function has a lot of variables which are just typed as `string` instead of as a specific string literal:

1. Templated strings like `${path}.${key}` get type `string`.
2. `Object.keys()` always returns `string[]`.
3. `node: Record<string, any>` means that the keys of `node` are any `string`.

Getting this strictly typed requires a combination of generic type parameters and `as` assertions.  There are many pieces to the puzzle.

To resolve #1, we can define a function that joins two string and returns the correct literal string value.

```
const joinPath = <Path extends string, Key extends string>(path: Path, key: Key) =>
  `${path}.${key}` as `${Path}.${Key}`

const myPath = joinPath('sub', 'number');
```

Now the type for `myPath` is `"sub.number"` instead of `string`.

#2 can be fixed with a simple `as` assertion `const keys = Object.keys(node) as (keyof typeof node)[]`, but it won't give us any useful information until we resolve #3, because the type for the specific keys of `node` is still just `string`.

In order for this to be strongly-typed for multiple levels of depth we need an association between the types of `node` and `path`.  We would need to know that the type of the current `node` matches the type from accessing the `path` on the root object.  But that's going to make this really complicated.  Assigning a variable to a conditional type like `Path` or `PathImpl` always requires an assertion.  It's going to be a real headache, so you might consider something less strict.

---

### Vaguely Type-Safe

```
type RecursiveSchema = {
  [K: string]: RecursiveSchema | string;
}
```

We can define a somewhat loose definition for your `schema` object.
The `RecursiveSchema` is an object with `string` keys.  The value for each key is either a `string` or another level of `RecursiveSchema`.

Because of how loose this is, `Path<RecursiveSchema>` is just `string`.  So it's easy to assign to it and our **issues #1-#3 above don't matter**.

We need to assign `node[key]` to a variable in the `walk` function in order for the `if` statement to properly refine the type.  But that's basically it.  **We don't need any generics or any `as` assertions.**  This function passes all type checks:

```
const walk = (node: RecursiveSchema, path?: string) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(node);
  for (let key in keys) {
    const value = node[key];
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      useController<RecursiveSchema>(path ? `${path}.${key}` : key);
    } else {
      walk(value, path ? `${path}.${key}` : key);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well thank you Linda. I tried to address all the problems you mentioned myself. But even then i had no luck so far. Anyway, all valid points. While your code is valid, it does not 100% solve my problem. The types i am using are given by the library mentioned. As far as i can see as soon as `RecursiveSchema` is not an abstract unlimit deep thing but a concrete fixed implementation it does not work, with the same problems. Still some interesting points that might help and might improve my problem.

Comment: @patman yes `RecursiveSchema` is a fixed implementation, but it does have infinite depth.