# TypeScript assert that a given type is finite

Tags: typescript, recursion, assertion

Some experimentation with typescript as presented me with a challenge: can you define a type which takes any form of sequential key object, analogous to a path in a filesystem, and uses it to recursively look up keys of an interface?

An example:

```js
interface someDeeplyNestedInterface {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: {
          e: any
           }
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

The answer, like all things TypeScript is yes you can. Here's my solution:

```js
type nonEmptyObject = {[k in keyof any]: any};
type _ObjPath<Obj, Key extends keyof Obj> = Obj extends nonEmptyObject ? [Key] | [Key, ...ObjPath<Obj[Key]>] : [Key];
type ObjPath<Obj> = _ObjPath<Obj, keyof Obj>;
```

Interestingly, this code won't compile, as the TSC warns about exceedingly, possibly infinite depth in the types - rightly so. I can confirm this snippet works as this compiled in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOKDezIDOYAXMiAK4C2ARtADTIAmwUpeA9tQFalFSgBzZAF8RAKDFgsKEOxABRSpikB5bhARhkAXmQ4A2gGtkoZIYjp2MZHBDoAuqVvphAbknTkAfTVcACnBgABYAPL4MANIWyBAAHpAgjARmFlbIvgB8OuncMfEQicmyCkqq6prIAPzI+lEOyAA+NXUMAHTtvgHBYdy1FvYZ9sikfQ7uUtg5-oGhmdk+3F2z3AzmltaZ7mIIckTInDxTSyEY2Fm6+gDkzFCXDJcHl0NwyVc3d8gP3E9bEygAchAiBBGABZCA0aA9LgMAgQAA2GjA7CgeQSSSOM2hGXOYmQ+OQcMRmhRaIKGP0oBg0BS6AYVJpBHI1AAygikSihpU8QSABRrMmFWlpXxVZC8pms9kk1FxdHJTpY3xGfpZbkEjXIQHAsEQ2hQaEqhyw5ls4nIqBZUggCAAN2gAEphmQ7Y7hjz8RLpRbBRiAAYAEhwDNRa2EfrF-OicvJyTWIty1WVayG1tdUCdaftGdcQA) briefly, although I can't seem to reproduce it. Hence my question; Is there a way to assert that a type is not infinite?

My thinking being, since this type always reads the keys of an object, if the given type `Obj` is not an object, there are no keys to be read, hence the recursive type reaches its terminal condition (`? ... : [Key]`). Understandably, this is difficult to infer programatically, so the question is a) whether there is a way to rewrite the type to avoid such errors, or b) assert that the type is not infinite, and the compiler should step through it without regard for depth?

> I understand that there is a potential XY problem here, however I'd like to emphasise that this code is not meant to be functional, rather an experiment of what myself as a programmer and the compiler are capable of. Avoiding *why are you trying to do this* questions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to obtain a valid path of an object?

Comment: That's correct. I hadn't thought to use the word *path*

Comment: You can check my [article](https://catchts.com/deep-pick) . You will find a list of related question and answers at the bottom of the article. If you don't have a time [here](https://tsplay.dev/WG5jkN) you have a simple example

Comment: If you are interested in `dot notation` - you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126879/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object-with-related-type#answer-69129328) answer

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. They work as expected. Is there any way to give specific feedback on why mine doesn't work?

Comment: Type of `nonEmptyObject` is incorrect. It should be `type nonEmptyObject = { [k in keyof any]: never };`