# How to type a dynamically growing object that is not part of the function params?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

## The Setup

I have a lib that provides helper functions to dynamically grow and use an object, and an arbitrary set of files that use this helper to define a list of steps this object will go through:

```js
// samplestepdefinition.ts
interface C {
  c1: string,
  c2: string
}

const isGreaterThanTwo = (number: number): boolean => number > 2

const steps = [
  Steps.initialize('a', 3),
  Steps.provide('b', 'a', isGreaterThanTwo),
  Steps.provide('c', 'b', (b: boolean): C => ({ c1: 'foo', c2: b ? 'bar' : 'baz' })),
  Steps.use('c.c2', console.log)
]
Steps.processSteps(steps) // logs 'bar'
```

```js
// stepslib-simplified.ts
import lodash_get from 'lodash/fp/get'
import lodash_set from 'lodash/fp/set'

interface StepContext extends Object { }
type StepResolver = (context: StepContext) => StepContext // but the output is modified


type ProviderFn = (valueToUse: any) => any
type Provide = (keyToSet: string, keyToUse: string, fn: ProviderFn) => StepResolver
const provide: Provide = (keyToSet, keyToUse, fn) => (context) =>
  lodash_set(keyToSet, fn(lodash_get(keyToUse, context)), context)

type Initialize = (keyToSet: string, value: any) => StepResolver
const initialize: Initialize = lodash_set

type UserFn = (valueToUse: any) => any
type Use = (keyToUse: string, fn: UserFn) => StepResolver
const use: Use = (keyToUse, fn) => context => fn(lodash_get(keyToUse, context))

const Steps = {
  provide,
  initialize,
  use,
  processSteps: (steps: StepResolver[]): void => {
    steps.reduce((prevContext, step) => step(prevContext), {})
  }
}
export default Steps
```

## The Challenge

In this example, there is no actual type validation. If the type definition of `isGreaterThanTwo` would take a string as argument, the code would not clash. Neither would replacing step 3 with `Steps.provide('c', 'b', (b: number): [...]`.

**Best Case**

I wonder if it wouldn't be possible to just infer all of these types by just changing the `stepslib` to track this dynamically growing object. ReturnType can be inferred from `ProviderFn` and hopefully `StepResolver` can return a compound type of whatever it got plus key+value from `Provider`.

I tried around a bit but couldn't figure out how this works.

**Alternative**

If that's not possible I could imagine having the `stepdefinition` file provide something like

```js
interface SpecificContext extends StepContext {
  a?: number
  b?: boolean
  c?: C
}
```

as a generic to `processSteps` to at least use that for type validation.

Here's what I tried:

```js
// stepslib-simplified.ts
import lodash_set from 'lodash/fp/set'

interface StepContext extends Object { }
type StepResolver = <Context extends StepContext>(context: Context) => Context // <- changed

// [...]

const Steps = {
  // [...]
  processSteps: <Context extends StepContext>(steps: StepResolver[]): void => { // <- changed
    steps.reduce((prevContext, step) => step<Context>(prevContext), {})
    // ^ Error: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Context'.
    // '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Context', but 'Context' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'StepContext'.
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to solve that?

*NOTE:*  I admit step 4 using `'c.c2'` is more advanced. I'd be glad to at least get a solution for providing a direct keys without dot-nesting.
I found out there is a way to evaluate strings like `<'${path}.${infer rest}'>` but don't yet know how that would be used there.

*EDIT:* [Stackblitz Code Editor link of this code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-b7bj4l?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [something like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMqQA4B4CSAaZAeQD5kBvAKGWQGsIBPAFQHsBVAZwgC5l2wpQAc2QBuKrQYtUEMAH4efASEFjqMEDwAUoDAFcwPHAEpkAXlKEKAXwoUEAGzjt2aTOywARZBAAekEAAmLgBKEAjMUAFYikIEcCD0xASM3n4QgS4epJTU1BgCAG5wkMjhIIq6CGARmnoARvbACMhQEHABzCD29MgBEPC69mAAwp2QfjweBPnARSV8EBjsPOiLWPH0cQnEANoAumbI+yaU4tQ2Z8j1jc18xU3IoMBgwHCNAF4QWADSqf5BvH4sWQKV8-xcZCsxE0dCYzGkBmQ3wIRXsum4IJOl1yLRkuigIGQIAgAHdXIt2JoyEdYVIZHseKj0cgrMgnMhQuFIj88IxiEZVLkLjjrg98swCsA+lgAIJ-dIA2HMGAgggAIXlGUBSkEBGGmoBkOhtPhMh4aoIJo4GJlBHUWh0+gAanAoDxGDsZXsTOZkMMjCs3J5ksgAGQcsIRKIWv3EbLY3KtMD4wnEsmrJaaBM4sAAC2A7AAdH0BkNRuAwXhs7kdoW63mC4WFksCDkce3qFbODwuyh2TFlFWOx2TQie5JTWAh8OcfbkOpq+c9tWBZdhblRc1dJxZQaXEqVXyYRPrTxbfONMhtCA9GAXW6QZ7vWZSAVmFKA+SlsG+eRq0mUyJUkv0pRdkAbIsSzgQYRjGSswNret8yLZt2FbMDOxPbsJDha02RcAddQwi8eAXGclxXQVzlsEVdAaMUoGYJBnE0LEOwAglwOQps3ELVoAkqCBNE0MpxinQFFh9eMZ2AFVNGbQtRxkNjyI4wkyDrQtRMrI4FKUsAGQkjBC3UES4L8HY9KwiBvRsGdWQgexOD-cijJMkAzIrCyrNwzhvSo4c1NKcywACnE7PbKwCAg4t+mgssQpMdlGACmwLjKPgjJcUxqAzIsnheN5gE+TQAHI4FKggAEYjEuQtxUlPoyrqSrkHK1rNFRKTkFRZBSAABlqnF6sYxqhNKhBWtKlqCE6t5uqpZg6gAKxlRk3isIxVzsTp2GYewIELexmEEeTeKgmDyzE2qMv2w7jtO1CRqYiAWK2iggA) will do?

(I've changed the structure a little just to get the basic idea how it works)

```
interface Step<I, O> {
  keyToUse: string ;
  keyToSet?: string;
  fn: (input: I) => O
}

class Steps<D extends Record<string, any>, T extends D> {
    private constructor(public readonly defaultContext: D, private steps: Step<any, any>[] = []) {

    }

    public static initialize<K extends string, T extends {}>(keyToSet: K, value: T) {
        return new Steps({ [keyToSet]: value } as Record<K,T>);
    }

    public provide<A extends keyof T, B extends string, C extends {}>(keyToSet: B, keyToUse: A, fn: (inputVar: T[A]) => C): Steps<D, T & Record<B, C>> {
        return new Steps(
          this.defaultContext,
          [...this.steps, {
            keyToUse: keyToUse as string,
            keyToSet: keyToSet,
            fn: fn
          }]
        );
    }

    public use<A extends keyof T>(keyToUse: A, fn: (inputVar: T[A]) => void): Steps<D,T> {
        return new Steps(
          this.defaultContext,
          [...this.steps, {
            keyToUse: keyToUse as string,
            fn: fn
          }]
        );
    }

    public process() {
      return this.steps.reduce((context, step) => {
        if (step.keyToSet) {
          return {...context, [step.keyToSet]: step.fn(context[step.keyToUse])}
        } else {
          step.fn(context[step.keyToUse]);
          return context;
        }
      }, this.defaultContext) as T;
    }
}

const steps =  Steps.initialize('a', 1)
    .provide('b', 'a', (val) => val > 0)
    .provide('c', 'b', (val) => ({objA: val}));

console.log(steps.defaultContext)
console.log(steps.process())
```

I have changed `Steps` to builder object, because we need to track our type `T` of the created object (aka. your `SpecificContext`). With array there is no way to track the type of the context.

### Edit: accessing nested properties

Thanks to [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69184238/17277491) by [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) the code can be enhanced to work with nested properties (I used the code from the anwser, so all the credit goes to *jcalz*).

Here is the *Flatten* type code by jcalz:

```
type Flatten<T, O = never> = Writable<Cleanup<T>, O> extends infer U ?
    U extends O ? U : U extends object ?
    ValueOf<{ [K in keyof U]-?: (x: PrefixKeys<Flatten<U[K], O>, K, O>) => void }>
    | ((x: U) => void) extends (x: infer I) => void ?
    { [K in keyof I]: I[K] } : never : U : never;

type Writable<T, O> = T extends O ? T : {
    [P in keyof T as IfEquals<{ [Q in P]: T[P] }, { -readonly [Q in P]: T[P] }, P>]: T[P]
}

type IfEquals<X, Y, A = X, B = never> =
    (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
    (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? A : B;

type Cleanup<T> =
    0 extends (1 & T) ? unknown :
    T extends readonly any[] ?
    (Exclude<keyof T, keyof any[]> extends never ?
        { [k: `${number}`]: T[number] } : Omit<T, keyof any[]>) : T;

type PrefixKeys<V, K extends PropertyKey, O> =
    V extends O ? { [P in K]: V } : V extends object ?
    { [P in keyof V as
        `${Extract<K, string | number>}.${Extract<P, string | number>}`]: V[P] } :
    { [P in K]: V };

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]

function lookup<T, K extends keyof Flatten<T>>(obj: T, key: K): Flatten<T>[K];
function lookup(obj: any, key: string) {
    const i = key.indexOf(".");
    return (i < 0) ? obj[key] : (lookup as any)(obj[key.substring(0, i)], key.substring(i + 1));
}
```

And here is your code with `Flatten`:

```
interface Step<I, O> {
  keyToUse: string ;
  keyToSet?: string;
  fn: (input: I) => O
}

class Steps<D extends Record<string, any>, T extends D> {
    private constructor(public readonly defaultContext: D, private steps: Step<any, any>[] = []) {

    }

    public static initialize<K extends string, T extends {}>(keyToSet: K, value: T) {
        return new Steps({ [keyToSet]: value } as Record<K,T>);
    }

    public provide<A extends keyof Flatten<T, Date>, B extends string, C extends {}>(keyToSet: B, keyToUse: A, fn: (inputVar: Flatten<T, Date>[A]) => C): Steps<D, T & Record<B, C>> {
        return new Steps(
          this.defaultContext,
          [...this.steps, {
            keyToUse: keyToUse as string,
            keyToSet: keyToSet,
            fn: fn
          }]
        );
    }

    public use<A extends keyof Flatten<T, Date>>(keyToUse: A, fn: (inputVar: Flatten<T, Date>[A]) => void): Steps<D,T> {
        return new Steps(
          this.defaultContext,
          [...this.steps, {
            keyToUse: keyToUse as string,
            fn: fn
          }]
        );
    }

    public process() {
      return this.steps.reduce((context, step) => {
        if (step.keyToSet) {
          return {...context, [step.keyToSet]: step.fn(lookup(context, step.keyToUse as keyof Flatten<typeof context>))}
        } else {
          step.fn(lookup(context, step.keyToUse as keyof Flatten<typeof context>));
          return context;
        }
      }, this.defaultContext) as T;
    }
}



interface C {
  c1: string,
  c2: string
}

const isGreaterThanTwo = (number: number): boolean => number > 2

Steps.initialize('a', 3)
  .provide('b', 'a', isGreaterThanTwo)
  .provide('c', 'b', (b: boolean): C => ({ c1: 'foo', c2: b ? 'bar' : 'baz' }))
  .use('c.c2', console.log)
  .process();
```

You can find [the complete code in sandbox here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-I2hE1zWg8P5-nUr7UM2TIAVygw8rIUwAAYACRHOUui8MomLYRmpyEcR4AphKUxRLoOTajBArfogv6PCkyKJmuqpML8kD-ICwIhJskSXDO8bgPA-jgL4QL8DqbZcpsx6GtExo8pacbnH6Km0cgKkSQsyyrJyGEWlaLEqXa5pcnhRzAdg4AyNgIQIsgUjZIg0DIASlEtpiWj4Y5zmrCE3yRJ5rQ+X5ZREQFZFTJsybipK5qaVcOlJeKPEbtsuz7IcJCtv6kEPCQjzeCoN6rAgKDqPAsi7tB4lIcxNpgsEVQpO8xmJpE-JTOciJTJ1ELFdCyrVYgtVIMgDVNewvVLFMP4DbcUxRd5yJmlydBsGssDpPyWitIw9QHO8ABEWhXYiypclA2BlOAKDvEdITIAeV7Gac-Iph8C0VN+1A-oiy2LH9txaJQZS8Ft0DvAekSwIiMLMTDcMI+9yAANTIGYiL3dm3ggKAsxQHAc1jYQ3gEK0eCqDITAAMp4JUzI6rtzEkPAnSUJAm1OdFyAPTz8As5A2BvB5wveWLKiIB8rTsGU2Ait2UQkwQoF2tQbOQKIIQACKqWOyAAEorPA4D0CECORD+cIviextpNzAzsNkCg4Ew+2eWUqw2+8qt5LANDIO+kaCIwKiYGU6DYIUSB4I0UzG5EXuwD7eCy4b4jIAblRrax-ApH+6R-jt3hcjm5qh+g4eyzgTetDksA7LAABeBStSeDs9m1RzYu8-K85L6vwpEPsFYm1foYMT0vSgiQaIX7OUO8mG3OPUt+jPeypXalvW7bbnhMVxO1zXgwN03XuKBiBQ1hJZVoFg4KhNBxu+3CjYSQPQoZs5jDx6mPCWUsVzrX4LzfmgtkBVkiIrZWiBVbYG2OAUaH8urf1-qcKsjxuyFBGuvfOJtIh6gvFbOgZ96yREKCkd2tlF5S2XvKNeRdN7MK5NgCglAtCx3jonZOiBU7YHCNwwYpwtAyN4VQGGG9gySK5OAuBUxVECxBrLLy0AJELwXuAie6id4QPEcowYyDkCK3MZiSq+jkBX0GHXLkd8I5lAFiEF+bU340yYj-PAjDR4mLUQgpBStCQqzVhgrBQRxqRH8ZAcuBDuxogxCQzh5DirckkUvV67DSGiHeOYuR-DBEJyTinEYej7FnBkVoEpCj85KJqYMDR8C2laIduYgYljrEtNsZIxxAxnG3zho3COD8aCQEoJvee6FckoAaVIfOWhuCB0gESfaYjIrs27B7dCsAHjvGWewLQhipZzPsQs7kdStlVLOCcs5JiJ5+keYrd4QMlp3MaDsw2TyYF800cfHx2CIS8RtN87AnFEQ5nsRKSAxYmD7IXm8xAHz4CNQqO8SFvzTkdOBbBd+sTQjgoeJC6FYsrmsLyZCyl6FYX0siA0spwjKmNGRMfEgdKcx128AzZQccpmbmyQMGgZghY6OqTQGwErora39odSgABxMMjNyClBIBoeA6R3j+UwQkOKVESG8AxSUFA5IDXxSZGkGw3hOGnUQO3TuPd3gAHJMCusiHYREGwtAPwUE-N1vBPXIHdSGqgKrtxqrIBqrVPqBh+qkgGxgbqaAhtdcGyI7xeBTBNfAM1JCgEWq3rQcVoaVAYpDdK3NxoM2YHAK62Udau6NsxETX17iNmupoDoGwVakCUHzZALQ6hoDxuQIm+AUyZldkVEAA).

Comment: Interesting, thank you bob. So one way to get it to work is to have a wrapping class keep track of the context. There is one key difference though between this code and what I was doing above, and that is the fact that I was able to define a list of steps that can be processed at a later point in time, whereas this just executes the changes immediately. So unfortunately I can't use something like this as is. But having an example of how this works with `<Record<K,T>>` gives me a good basis to fiddle around with further.

Comment: Glad to help. Yes, you keep the context in your `Steps` class, which acts like builder. Every time you add your *step*, it will return new (or the same) instance of `Steps` which holds the new context. I can't think of solution which would work for the array method, because every *step* inside the array must somehow know about the previous *steps*.

Comment: I have changed the example solution. You see you can do the same thing even if you don't process it immediately.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks a lot! One note for anyone looking over this code and, like me, scratching their heads why `Flatten<T, Date>` takes a date of all things - it's just a remnant of the original question the Flatten code was written for and can just be simplified to `Flatten<T>`.