# How to allow unknown string in a typed object?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes a json key as a parameter. In order to allow autocompletion, I have typed this parameter. It works.

However, if I write the key with dynamic value, ex: `CAR.BRAND.${color}`, typescript recognises it as an invalid string, that doesn't match the required schema.

How to allow random strings as a parameter while keeping the autocompletion?

Here is the code:

```js
// json
{
  hello: "hello",
  world: "world",
  name: {
    john: "john",
    doe: "doe"
  }
}

// .ts file
type KeyPrefix<T extends string> = T extends "" ? "" : `.${T}`;

export type KeyPath<T> = (
  T extends object
    ? {
        [K in Exclude<keyof T, symbol>]: `${K}${KeyPrefix<KeyPath<T[K]>>}`;
      }[Exclude<keyof T, symbol>]
    : ""
) extends infer D
  ? Extract<D, string>
  : never;

 type Path = KeyPath<typeof myjson>;

 function foo(key: Path){
    return key
 }
 
 // expected output:
 foo("nam") // autocomplete suggestions: name.john, name.doe. 
 foo("name.doe") // no error.
 foo("name." + value) // no error. (currently returns an error)
```

I've tried to allow a random string entry like this:

```js
type i18nSchema<T> = T & { [key: string]: string };
type Path = KeyPath<i18nSchema<typeof myjson>>;
```

It removes the error, but the autocompletion is gone.

How to fix this?

Comment: A snippet only makes sense when its features (e.g. executing the code in it) adds something useful to the question. An unrelated syntax error doesn't help the reader of the question.

Comment: I've replaced the foo function by a very basic one on purpose. The original foo() is very long, and doesn't add any value to the question, which is about typing a parameter. The function output doesn't matter here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eliminate nevers to make union possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668055/eliminate-nevers-to-make-union-possible)

Comment: You can also find this answer helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67242871/declare-a-type-that-allows-all-parts-of-all-levels-of-another-type#answer-67247652  and my article https://catchts.com/deep-pick

Comment: Hi @captain-yossarian, I've tried your version, but it doesn't work. The autocomplete suggest incomplete paths (suggests `user` in addition to `user.john`, and `user.doe`), and returns an error if I write a dynamic string. Here is a codesandbox with the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-robinson-8b1cj?file=/src/App.tsx:0-762

Comment: If you meant that it does not work because ` foo("name." + value)` than it is not completely true because TS considers this operation unsafe. Try this ` foo(`name.${value}`)` - it works

Comment: I get a `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"hello" | "world" | "name.john" | "name.doe"'.`