# Get typescript to infer tuple parameters types

Tags: typescript, type-constraints, typescript-types

I'm creating a function like [Lodash's at()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#at). I have typing working if the user passes in tuples like this:

```
at(obj, ['key1'] as const, ['key2', 'key3'] as const)
```

I want the user to be able to call the function naturally, without tricks like "`as const`". Can it be done? Here is the craziness I have so far:

```
type PropertyAtPath<T, Path extends readonly any[]> = Path extends []
  ? T
  : Path extends readonly [infer First, ...infer Rest]
  ? First extends keyof T
    ? PropertyAtPath<T[First], Rest>
    : undefined
  : unknown;

type At<T, Paths extends ReadonlyArray<ReadonlyArray<any>>> = {
  [I in keyof Paths]: Paths[I] extends readonly any[]
    ? PropertyAtPath<T, Paths[I]>
    : never;
};

declare function at<T, Paths extends ReadonlyArray<ReadonlyArray<any>>>(
  object: T,
  ...paths: Paths
): At<T, Paths>;
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTge0nUBBYMCGwAWAeAFQBpZscoIAPYCAOwBMBnKOCTehWgGxCk1pABtALoA+KAF5SuCtTpMoIgFBQoAfigEVUAFzTyVGg2at2nHooCWtAGYQ4UAGKW4jYCQB0X63YcAlCDdhbQ1nV2BZIwUAawgQBBtNbVUNeCR7NAwyQkEwoJIAt1Fk3SgAVwYIG2sIem09CujaBAB3WgBuJSVQSCh0QhIsXGZDeWYAs24QVDg4TBA8CY4pmbmF-hBRLckoAG9tQQBJKGsoWPjEoZxGYT0rxiPhSLGWNmWLDeVVFNhEZEyrgN9A9DmISnpaBAAG72ToAX06SnoEAAxlxMKwoDYKijgJZOHxgED7s9jFAluZprN5os3pTVjSNltRAAKbQIABGACtUcA9MRtF4PGAyIw7qKlABKPT9YjA0SIgD0ypVqtVXWsNDgNkwKOgAHk9tpMBCygBbDmw7QcmXUha7KAovRuODWADmUDhCqUcK6yLRGOgKM4bignK5en1iOwLPDJEEACJMAmnphmMHaG5Je0oMqoIwcAgylx6FBLYpaObLXAniyWgg4NF3ZKlDG44okyns7nFfnC8XS+XBJWLfZa80IvXG82um3ufGExyEyQAAwkBMolN8dMh4DdvMFoslsvQQQu921qdN2hultzrkLper9eb4T73uHgcnxTnm-jhCTg2163koQA)

Answer (score 4):

In case someone stumbles upon this in the future.

If you just want to have the function infer a *tuple* instead of an *array* without using `as const`, there are multiple options.

---

The preferred option is to use a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types):

```
function fn<T extends string[]>(tuple: [...T]) { return tuple }

const r = fn(["a", "b", "c"])
//    ^? const r: ["a", "b", "c"]
```

---

There is also this alternative:

```
function fn<T extends string[] | [string]>(tuple: T) { return tuple }
```

This behaves identical to the first example in most cases. However I encountered some differences in the past where the [second solution works](https://tsplay.dev/wER7yN) but the [first one does not](https://tsplay.dev/mZj1om).

---

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NdYEnm)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to validate second argument, to avoid passing invalid object paths.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67242871/declare-a-type-that-allows-all-parts-of-all-levels-of-another-type#answer-67247652), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668055/eliminate-nevers-to-make-union-possible/68672512?noredirect=1#comment121362429_68672512), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126879/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object-with-related-type#answer-69129328) and [here, in my blog](https://catchts.com/deep-pick#all_keys) you can find an explanation of how this code works.

First three links are from stackoverflow. I have provided explanation in comments.

```js
type Structure = {
    foo: {
        a: [1, 'hello'],
        b: 2,
    }
    bar: {
        c: 3,
        d: 4,
    }
}

declare var data: Structure;

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Elem = string;

type Acc = Record<string, any>

/**
 * Just like Array.prototype.reduce predicate/callback
 * Receives accumulator and current element
 * - if element extends one of accumulators keys -> return  acc[elem]
 * - otherwise return accumulator
 */
type Callback<Accumulator extends Acc, El extends Elem> =
    El extends keyof Accumulator ? Accumulator[El] : Accumulator

type Reducer<
    Keys extends Elem,
    Accumulator extends Acc = {}
    > =
    /**
     * If Keys extends a string with dot
     */
    Keys extends `${infer Prop}.${infer Rest}`
    /**
     * - Call Reducer recursively with last property
     */
    ? Reducer<Rest, Callback<Accumulator, Prop>>
    /**
     *  - Otherwise obtain whole property 
     */
    : Keys extends `${infer Last}`
    ? Callback<Accumulator, Last>
    : never
{

    type Test1 = Reducer<'foo.a', Structure> // 1
    type Test2 = Reducer<'bar.d', Structure> // 4
}

/**
 * Compute all possible property combinations
 */
type KeysUnion<T, Cache extends string = ''> =
    /**
     * If T extends string | number | symbol -> return Cache, this is the end
     */
    T extends PropertyKey ? Cache : {
        /**
         * Otherwise, iterate through keys of T, because T is an object
         */
        [P in keyof T]:
        /**
         * Check if property extends string
         */
        P extends string
        /**
         * Check if it is the first call of this utility,
         * because Cache is empty
         */
        ? Cache extends ''
        /**
         * If it is a first call,
         * call recursively itself, go one level down - T[P] and initialize Cache - `${P}`
         */
        ? KeysUnion<T[P], `${P}`>
        /**
         * If it is not first call of KeysUnion and not the last
         * Unionize Cache with recursive call, go one level dow and update Cache
         */
        : Cache | KeysUnion<T[P], `${Cache}.${P}`>
        : never
    }[keyof T]

{
    //"foo" | "bar" | "foo.a" | "foo.b" | "bar.c" | "bar.d"
    type Test1 = KeysUnion<Structure>
}

type ExtractPath<T extends string> = Extract<T, string>

type Mapper<Obj, Paths extends ExtractPath<KeysUnion<Obj>>[]> = {
    [Prop in keyof Paths]: Reducer<Paths[Prop] & string, Obj>
}

const at = <
    Obj,
    Key extends ExtractPath<KeysUnion<Obj>> & string,
    Keys extends Key[]
>(obj: Obj, keys: [...Keys]): Mapper<Obj, Keys> =>
    null as any


type Result = Mapper<Structure, ['foo.a.1', 'bar.c']>

const lookup = at(data, ['foo.a.0', 'bar.c']) // [1, 3]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBXAxsR9oF4oG8CwAUFMVAGYD25AXLoSfVAIY0DaAjADRQDkAFhABsB5bgF0OdBsQBGNAEwSiJAL6SZjeDXxKpyGgGZFU4gBMaAFiMrCqgoRMRkAjdABuGqCcbBmsBCjQMAG5CQlBIKAA1RgFECABnAB4AFQA%20KGxklgBrCBByUihk0VCCcOgAUQEIAFsMqHiEAEsAOwBzELsy8GgAQWRkeoAlR3J4E0TG%20Fa2rkYWkFTSgHoAKlW6VagAKURGqAEm3Khe%20HhGEAA6MHhyYDuey4wTFGgbiBMm5G8IZe%20haSMZDZTZQEbICBNVwJJgDRA1RDOe7wJgtExQZDoDAtYBQQS1CA40EAWigTUK%20JqhNxEAAHsBCSZ4lByC1oAVYZiEUixszciBmcT0hhAi1iEDkCxKSUiFtSXd%20PAAO5NeLQEXoMUS%20GI7xjTbLMI9KAABWeXx%20iX6XN1yLx9MZzOtXCq9oZaOZVVq6Uwaigrrp7qZUH5HOtOp5KIA-Cc4dy9fAWFVRFAaOH48jSuUwR9XvBEn6ANJ5ZmBx3%206o1KzEdO2sZu8vW%20o4Wz0H1%20tYbHTELYASUKxYFDY9TAazXaUBVwF4njufqgq0N3cHpYdI4ABgASHCtUgQFFm8hgZSXbe7-c5xrKdcd9bzuVQADCMQEOZeEJRGEx8HiUMEIEnJppwORh9huI991Ae8l3oGMRnffdEhGRouDND4LQZK04zreBUNuMBUiWbtO3vYhSQAeWnfcVTVFlpB8VpJwAK3IaooHAyAzlAKBoL9GgV2HYMtx3Fo9xRAAZUDgGvP0YzQz5vkw2tIy4STGiI%20gaDZaF4EIbQ-WzZIEmANhhlzD9Em4ChyEuRhuC4OAkFQdAIHSZZligNgDONIzGjkMyEPzbhAXgS4THsvwnMCVyoHcqBzBsFY71lJ9yBqMBEAZJghHY8h4l-aQ2I4yCAOQNLpFabwmlZeIDSNCIVwAVRaaqWhSLhn2QfhBOZKYZnqbhuHbYjkoYPtCmSHqx2mCcAB8oBaeFpAveb4hAGppFYqAhSgDV4DFTr%20C4adVTJZkqLxNFeO7SayxHQ9ONAQcoBjQ7oC0ecSBI7sxqgSjFRoiAuCA-cfigadbkQNoZ35ZkOWSLhlu%20PZoEm075jopjHGAT6SEXXGoBYE0yTFUMJtEKgCe%204weyffhgTJQpivgbi7uDPr2gJhcYOMYm2d68c2ip0aaa2R96eyRmyVxU6LtIJof1xf5Xw5E7mUyppDlAaspC2JHGBRp9%20m607ajAKCfvofHLeIV6gW6-meG4YWuxphcoH7aWztHeXFYxF8dd%205XdscdBf2hAQAKAtUBFILg2nIFk2QOCAI9nJUxVJLITRTeZ0VaICmhiJoAC9oDe7aoGEk0ZJtnseakGMmpa1kUiJ8Qq%203Gv1w04xqdFj3CiA72WjuMgFf2YOOWb1rUXRUfcQu5xGi5rZmta0vy-t6ApxnL8w7-f2hHjxPWWgao05McglTnqBEDALwsre1eG4YGgK-mmfW%20zjvhLek8u7Xl7lILSqd9x%20mUDkPI8MZR6Q7MsAARNZBBUB5oIJCigtB1lbKYKgEgyglxpC4PQRoS4yBiEhTCgg7yERfImXqF-NqjkAguSIrYeqlR6TnFQCabwvAUhTQ5m0H0-ouFAmAO1aaMwiIcKgAAWUYGATiiRyLSCYqhPhq4gyejETwvhiRGEqLUYRFgogRHaHoETfCJMQzQMKLw6c8QKZvjzIkBxvB4hWKPCmAAZFI9oXBVFMTYaUMqLR9jeHqAWbsQSdbPUdhUXRwB3EGJLOvVuQTCJQD8UIuJJYpqDlMYQVIAAKcgaiaCxNsQKVglw6krlEAAShoAopRiEqkrh9MAhaiJXygVRCAUosjkKIlxNgVpyjmHOQwFwFgVkCGMEuGwCKwVSHIDEDIggYT9jCHINke%209RvAlMfowWZ8ybKLIAAwrMoesppsUPLsC4PoGUQA)

Above code expects `obj` to be fully infered, I mean `obj` should be `as const`.

If you want to handle `arrays` and empty tuples you might want to use this implementation:

```js
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]
{
    // 1 | "John"
    type _ = Values<{ age: 1, name: 'John' }>
}

type IsNever<T> = [T] extends [never] ? true : false;
{
    type _ = IsNever<never> // true 
    type __ = IsNever<true> // false
}

type IsTuple<T> =
    (T extends Array<any> ?
        (T['length'] extends number
            ? (number extends T['length']
                ? false
                : true)
            : true)
        : false)
{
    type _ = IsTuple<[1, 2]> // true
    type __ = IsTuple<number[]> // false
    type ___ = IsTuple<{ length: 2 }> // false
}

type IsEmptyTuple<T extends Array<any>> = T['length'] extends 0 ? true : false
{
    type _ = IsEmptyTuple<[]> // true
    type __ = IsEmptyTuple<[1]> // false
    type ___ = IsEmptyTuple<number[]> // false
}

/**
 * If Cache is empty return Prop without dot,
 * to avoid ".user"
 */
type Concat<
    Cache extends PropertyKey[],
    Prop extends string | number | symbol
    > =
    Cache extends []
    ? [Prop]
    : [...Cache, Prop]

/**
 * Simple iteration through object properties
 */
type HandleObject<Obj, Cache extends PropertyKey[]> = {
    [Prop in keyof Obj]:
    | Cache
    // concat previous Cacha and Prop
    | Concat<Cache, Prop>
    // with next Cache and Prop
    | Path<Obj[Prop], Concat<Cache, Prop>>
}[keyof Obj]

type Path<Obj, Cache extends PropertyKey[] = []> =
    (Obj extends PropertyKey
        // return Cache
        ? Cache
        // if Obj is Array (can be array, tuple, empty tuple)
        : (Obj extends Array<any>
            // and is tuple
            ? (IsTuple<Obj> extends true
                // and tuple is empty
                ? (IsEmptyTuple<Obj> extends true
                    // call recursively Path with `-1` as an allowed index
                    ? Path<PropertyKey, Concat<Cache, -1>>
                    // if tuple is not empty we can handle it as regular object
                    : HandleObject<Obj, Cache>)
                // if Obj is regular  array call Path with union of all elements
                : Path<Obj[number], [...Cache, `${number}`]>
            )
            // if Obj is neither Array nor Tuple nor Primitive - treat is as object    
            : HandleObject<Obj, Cache>
        )
    )


type Reducer<Obj, Props extends Array<PropertyKey>> =
    Props extends []
    ? Obj
    : (Props extends [infer Fst, ...infer Tail]
        ? (Tail extends string[]
            ? (
                Obj extends Array<any>
                ? (
                    Fst extends `${number}`
                    ? Reducer<Obj[number], Tail>
                    : never)
                : (Fst extends keyof Obj
                    ? Reducer<Obj[Fst], Tail>
                    : never
                )
            )
            : never
        )
        : never
    )

type Validation<T> = IsNever<T> extends true ? [never] : []

const at = <
    Obj,
    Keys extends string[]
>(obj: Obj, keys: [...Keys], ...validation: Validation<Reducer<Obj, Keys>>): Reducer<Obj, [...Keys]> =>
    null as any


type Structure = {
    empty: [],
    tuple: [1, 2, 3],
    array: { age: Array<{ surname: string }> }[]
}


declare const data: Structure

/**
 * Tests
 */

// [1, 2, 3]
const _ = at(data, ['tuple'])

// const __: {
//     age: Array<{
//         surname: string;
//     }>;
// }
const __ = at(data, ['array', '0'])

// const ___: {
//     surname: string;
// }[]
const ___ = at(data, ['array', '2', 'age'])

// const ____: {
//     surname: string;
// }
const ____ = at(data, ['array', '0', 'age', '2'])

/**
 * Expected never
 */
{
    const _ = at(data, ['tupl'],) // error
    const __ = at(data, ['array', 'w']) // error
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIBqBDANgV1gZwDwBUA+eAXnjwG0BrWSAewDMyBdUAb1Hk-gHpv4BGeAB94AIgBStABYA7URy5Q48APokkaTLlbxkAc1gAuAQBp4M5AFsj8AOSTZt+AF8CoZ6AgwEASSwA5WAA3WAAnfCJScjwmeFgAD3BYGQATLHhyGWCw2IB+eHBQzHhjejQsWABuNgVOJQQ1Uj9AkPCs1qJeAqKEWoLvVUb4ZuzwwsxOvjLUCvdPEHrhrDx0aFRYCJI+gAo8OMTktPgAQVDQ5EgcZBlIIly+rnhd8lt1mT1wKVtYhKTU9Jk6EsACMwg9Hlx8ttASCwvs-kcKK9kh8viwQBDMRD8tNZhisQTjONYABKcGYok9Mn4inwXGkmo0-rKIZ+FZrDbkfhmABMTEm3UwfUWKlZy1W6xwMNBoXI-J4U3KsGFA1FYvZkp0b1Rxh5LgF9LmYAWAz8AFFLNAoBqNntfod0qdzpdrrdImQXtrPt94Q74AAGeD5YklOlKxmPEXqc2W60SznyrrElUssUWq2QG04LmJxUzZVMkWi6NYdNxjlSoEyuUG8MgDzG7gAKibHCbw0YAGFkABjKQIACW6Vgscg8FCsHA6FCMngAAVQrRoPAAO4Dz60dDgeApWjgExtgq0XRBWgDlJiAB06AqoXkGKb3C8yk7tBkPeQ4BwfW7fYQ9v+edFzgUIoAAaRoOUDyZBcl19QCsEKAd3mEcwqzhEQsEgEFaFQPpIh-Xt+3go45T6fJyFg6B0UeYxyEvBjf37MwqPRUBm1bB94AAZQHS11ngdcwk-Ac3wKKRF3QPQpHgWhgQAK1gHtt2gYCwnAAdsDbJ8TWUAAJa4UnWAB5BSlK-Uz5LMJj-wOQCqPUyAIMgGt1HYJlKOAwTZ2oOhGEsphDD6EQbL6LoezfD8VInIJRJveAmOQXRUiApdgoSyLPxwGyWOAtwmS6NdPnMX4EqIhBDNS6B0rnT8pBwSzPKXJhrMyr8cqqgh8ucKgaAYeAAvmRZas+BqFOs8qSPSBzQKcyDYiieViB2SypqqxznPJBVx0nadZ1CplHnyA6CS6Ad-IUwTHTOC4ng-WdQV0G7IDMKcOTMEcMwKeNqUJJ5VoAo4nQuK4bnyglHi6Sqh2+jktqOp42XjMb5KIQH0mTQ6Ic4KGUregSYc+qB4axKEYwzLNLLRuyjkx7HsfCtBUB2ntpywAcQlQMcRpkoqZIAAwAWn4fndHSa5dFQVBaBXWAL2QlIEhJ7H8h5nAZvAmhWvfLKOuFrrlYhs7GHxwcAT3OJR1XBB7vgKRDIJ7dkHSCc9HQVBkFCWSzOUw2-oM1ITJ9izxrKv8CF++nIb4c6BsumHXfdz3OE9514A-KX5zq1d1xk9AZFE2d+qZuJ1msGRwCwP2uGMNXGulHIzHoxjyrMfmABJWAb0JnH5-lDcjhmY4u+SrpK3O4WBscZFoL2bXMWegL49cOYQQXulgT8x+d73FOUx5DeMAOjNgSzzJRibw62wf4GpIaBgAJTl9AezCC+quHGnruddW1Nm5yupbBgsBT+CJ0hkSZPkSyfRjDbCoqAv05BkL0DhAAMUQmYBil5kFwjwMgAcqAaKkyeHggha1EKhGQnoCBUcoTV04ADL+Jxnqg1uPQoMTx2GPHQdudG8AO5d3Qj3fmXDITwCfikF+b965CJamQfBqBwZRyxMYdoYQb5R1gTwtavl+rQKxsojhEipHhEajwuRpDFGiM4Ko0Y7CNFYgcbSNRoRr5bVsa0Pod9dIIBQKgc8Ik3ybCaAEUYmw+Ehgoi42IdE2IgAijIRCuhtykG-EySy0FHjOQQQhJC7wIEEG2HJeSxgMnwF8lgOiWDslyKwUENAASNJvmMH4xphccDGNfqY0O2SuokmMJ06Rodm6XhqZEJRnBASZx3q6eYz4EDcXGMpacCBSDuUeETSAsTMmKHjHRbk8AeRmAAMwtT6KnC4xgdD6BsFPHAOgsB7SsDYChVD9QuAgQ2eYisewewnOnN8SSUifmQMYRZRRlkTnmBxQ8eBsCV20tCvgXJeQnPRAkpJQxPzbGBeAZATdbCm2+N48KgLtyiiuexPgjwbnGDue5LoBJHkzmecYV57xqggEZVwVwnKugNgxeSrF4AcUgoJRcyAtgzC2H9MSpFALElCpUJSrl1KuDMosNYNleS9B8r4D1dFZLBjCtFXi8Vz0pV2B5Ja2wNy5WNj4IK41yr4AMrVZwDVrL4Dst1VSlwoAnVqhNbi-FGRbUWulbK6VdrpXWqYCSlsh4zTxDgMpOWJVPEPh0usrggb1DYpDQS-G3wTAkm2mERcrimSBuDWKsNEqbUrmJeWs4s8jRAA)

Comment: It looks like you've shown an example of how to make the inferred type of a single argument be a tuple. I'm not sure how to use this in my case, where I want each variadic argument to be inferred as a tuple. Is there some part of your answer I can apply to my situation?

Also, FYI, that playground link is broken for me.

Comment: @EricSimonton my bad. Updated

Comment: That's cool stuff. Thank you for taking the time to make, then update your answer. While this brilliantly removes the need for the user to specify `as const`, it also requires them to provide a dot-separated string path. Can the typing be done so that they can pass in tuples to specifying their paths?

Comment: Could you please provide expected behavior? I m not sure I understood

Comment: For example remove the `as const` part of what I put in my question, leading to: `at(obj, ['key1'], ['key2', 'key3'])`. For other examples see lines 30 and 33 in the playground link of my question. I would like the user to be able to call my function like that (without `as const` or other tricks) and for the typing to still work.

Comment: @EricSimonton aha, I got it

Comment: @EricSimonton made an update