# how to define unboxing method parameters type

Tags: typescript

I have a method with the following signature

```
function unboxer(data, ...unbox) {
    return unbox.reduce((acc, key) => acc ? acc[key] : acc, data);
}
```

it will iteratively go over supplied keys in unbox array until value is unboxed.
example:

```
unboxer({a: 'somevalue1', b: {c: 'somevalue2', d: {e: 'somevalue3'}}}, ['b', 'c'])
```

will return somevalue2

```
unboxer({a: 'somevalue1', b: {c: 'somevalue2', d: {e: 'somevalue3'}}}, ['a'])
```

will return somevalue1

what is the correct type for unbox parameter? I'd like to reflect that it contains iterative keyof values. Something along the lines of:

```
unboxer(data: T, unbox: [keyof T, keyof data[keyof T],keyof data[keyof data[keyof T]],.....]
```

however expression should create a connection between each level of unboxing keys. Meaning, for array ['a','e'] I should receive a compilation error for object:

```
{a: 'somevalue1', b: {c: 'somevalue2', d: {e: 'somevalue3'}}}
```

Comment: I believe that your question is a duplicate of one of these answers: [first - see second part of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449511/get-typescript-to-infer-tuple-parameters-types/69450150#69450150), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449511/get-typescript-to-infer-tuple-parameters-types/69450150#69450150),  [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126879/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object-with-related-type#answer-69129328) and my [article](https://catchts.com/deep-pick)

Comment: If one of above answers work for you please let me know

Comment: You can use `Paths` from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436959/1113002

Comment: @captain-yossarian,
Thanks for the references. Yes, question is a duplication of the one referenced. I haven't checked whether solution works in my case yet but it seems to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Optional chaining should work, e.g. `data?.b?.c`