# Is there a way in Typescript to verify that a string key is valid for a type?

Tags: typescript

Sorry about the vague wording of the question.

Let's say I have a type like this:

```
type TestObject = {
  arr: Array<{x: number, y: Array<{z: string}}>>;
  obj: {[key: string]: number;
}
```

I'd like to be able to enforce that paths are valid - ideally at compile time, but runtime would be okay, along these lines:

```
function setValue<T>(object: T, path: string, value: unknown) {
  // perform the set operation
}
```

My intention is that the following should work:

```
const o: TestObject = { arr: [], obj: {} };
setValue<TestObject>(o, "arr[0].x", 1);
setValue<TestObject>(o, "arr[0].y[2].z", "hello world");
setValue<TestObject>(o, "obj['x']", 1);
```

But if you tried this, it should fail, as there is no `TestObject.a`:

```
setValue<TestObject>(o, "a", 1);
```

Ideally this would be implemented in such a way that the developer would get Intellisense and errors in the IDE, but a runtime solution would be okay as well.

Comment: I think it's impossible for your case because the string is a type itself, and the compiler cannot predict your string path as a type

Comment: Have you tried `setValue(<TestObject>(o, "obj[0]", {"k":1}` this?

Comment: There is no way TS can read a string path but maybe `lodash.get` https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get or `ramda.path` https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path could be of help to this use case for the runtime.

Comment: I believe your question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668055/eliminate-nevers-to-make-union-possible/68672512?noredirect=1#comment121362429_68672512), at least it very close. However, you can check [my](https://catchts.com/deep-pick) article

Comment: Other answers that might be relevant: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67242871/declare-a-type-that-allows-all-parts-of-all-levels-of-another-type#answer-67247652), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668055/eliminate-nevers-to-make-union-possible/68672512?noredirect=1#comment121362429_68672512), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449511/get-typescript-to-infer-tuple-parameters-types/69450150#69450150) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126879/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object-with-related-type#answer-69129328)

Comment: xIf you want to handle square bracket notation like `arr[0]`, I can update the answer

Answer (score 0):

TS doesn't allow for checking properties that come as strings.

The way you have setup your `TestObject` it will complain that you don't have an index type defined on it when you'll try to access properties using string indexes.