# How to set default value to param that has type keyof (from an explicit type) in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, default-parameters, keyof

I am having trouble in Typescript passing default values to a function similar to `pick` from **lodash**.

The function accepts an object of known (non-generic) interface and a set of keys to pick and return from the object.

Regular (no default params) declaration of the function works properly, however, I do not seem able to set an array as a **default value** for the parameter that selects the properties to pick.

```js
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: string;
    phone: string;
}

const defaultProps = ['name', 'age'] as const;


function pick<T extends keyof Person>(obj: Person, props: ReadonlyArray<T> = defaultProps): Pick<Person, T> {    
    return props.reduce((res, prop) => {
        res[prop] = obj[prop];
        return res;
    }, {} as Pick<Person,T>);
}

const testPerson: Person = {
    name: 'mitsos',
    age: 33,
    address: 'GRC',
    phone: '000'
};
```

If you remove the default value `= defaultProps` it compiles successfully and the returned type is also correct from an example call such as: `const testPick = pick(testPerson, ['name']);`

However, setting the default value produces the following error:

```
Type 'readonly ["name", "age"]' is not assignable to type 'readonly T[]'.
  Type '"name" | "age"' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    '"name" | "age"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'keyof Person'.
      Type '"name"' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        '"name"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'keyof Person'.
```

How can I successfully pass the default values to the `props` param?

***Typescript Playground** link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3ESXI9aQK7kBG0ViWRwAJqKgQMGGnQYgWbYgAcAFji5ymrAL4ECCHHWSiI8bgBswqKFmUZkAXmQBtAORlKbgDTI3HCDcAXREHQxA6Vn0YbhAEMGAcZGVgBABrAB4AFWQIAA9IEFEHNIgATywYNEwcAD4ACiw+ACsadChsEF9lW3saACUIMRwLMoBBKCg4MuzapxMzOEtrXowASjbUzPbO3yy5vGElZEkwbihcHrsMADpJUW4kevrJDG7etacD4+FXlyvlCFnE1mv9ekEhMISKdzrhXpDiDpfHgdKE0FsMjscN59mtdPpwsZIHQsSA2jVcM5CMJPFw3ORgGBsBgfMcAjQAMwc7xs8SvGR+ADi-QAwqzhGoNDQ3AAGOVuAg6VhAA)*

#### UPDATE

After playing around a bit I tried using conditional types and managed to get the function signature working, but having problems with reduce now not being recognized correctly:

```js
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: string;
    phone: string;
}

const defaultProps = ['name', 'age'] as const;

type DefaultProps = typeof defaultProps;

type PropsOrDefault<T extends keyof Person> = DefaultProps | ReadonlyArray<T>;

type PickedPropOrDefault<T extends PropsOrDefault<keyof Person>> = T extends DefaultProps ? Pick<Person, DefaultProps[number]> : Pick<Person, T[number]>;


function pick<T extends keyof Person>(obj: Person, props: PropsOrDefault<T> = defaultProps): PickedPropOrDefault<PropsOrDefault<T>> {    
    return props.reduce<PickedPropOrDefault<PropsOrDefault<T>>>((res, prop) => {
        res[prop] = obj[prop];
        return res;
    }, {} as PickedPropOrDefault<PropsOrDefault<T>>);
}

const testPerson: Person = {
    name: 'mitsos',
    age: 33,
    address: 'GRC',
    phone: '000'
};

const result = pick(testPerson) //  Pick<Person, "name" | "age">
const result2 = pick(testPerson, ['phone']) // Pick<Person, "phone">
const result3 = pick(testPerson, ['abc']) // expected error
```

**[Updated Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3ESXI9aQK7kBG0ViWRwAJqKgQMGGnQYgWbYgAcAFji5ymrAL4ECCHHWSiI8bgBswqKFmUZkAXmQBtAORlKbgDTI3HCDcAXREHQxA6VgIwAE9lFAARMzhLa1t7J2RY+KwYE2TUmzsMKOyUIvsAeSgk8ysAHgAVZAgAD0gQUQcAawgY3LRMHAA+TNqUqwqHAB9kACUIMRwLGIBBKCg4GKbh0rjy4ARe0Qrq8dSmlvaITocps4KG3v689ChsEGHR52a2jq7kOdJukHAB+NCHbr1N4fXxAtLFFwgXgCKBBUY0VCQ6FDEC+RpIlHQdFRAgwbggBBgYA4ZDKbG-a63ZDPAYwkYACiwfAAVpjcb5lCDMSCHnUwDtMqZxVMAJSYyEQE7pMUTCX3GqPCWNL74YRKZCSMDcKC4IXFAB0klE3CQ0MVyrsqouGvhOy+HI5kgwgvSsqco0IwmE3pc5uUIWc3J5YfSQSEweIRpNuG9CeIOl8eB0oQhRyVp014uhoqLavdst0+nCxkgdHZIH571pziDJE8XDc5GAYGwGB8BoCNAAzMPvIPxN6ZH4AOJzADCA+Eag0NDcAAZN24CDoojWwIapKlMvSjhy69Zcf6APTX4hYo445t45AAIg7r+Qs1fAVfwwMRgHt6qQAEwnpC55SJez6+O4K4gIEQQ3neD5Qg2vivvBEB-gBERAUeVjDuBZ4Xuhrj+HwCDBMhVzxFSSotBsWBQEAA)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overload `pick` function:

```js
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: string;
    phone: string;
}

const defaultProps = ['name', 'age'] as const;

type DefaultProps = typeof defaultProps;

function pick(obj: Person): Pick<Person, DefaultProps[number]>
function pick<Prop extends keyof Person, Props extends ReadonlyArray<Prop>>(obj: Person, props: Props): Pick<Person, Props[number]>
function pick<T extends keyof Person>(obj: Person, props = defaultProps) {
    return props.reduce((res, prop) => ({
        ...res,
        [prop]: obj[prop]
    }), {} as Pick<Person, T>);
}

const testPerson = {
    name: 'mitsos',
    age: 33,
    address: 'GRC',
    phone: '000'
};

const result = pick(testPerson) //  Pick<Person, "name" | "age">
const result2 = pick(testPerson, ['phone']) // Pick<Person, "phone">
const result3 = pick(testPerson, ['abc']) // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3ESXI9aQK7kBG0ViWRwAJqKgQMGGnQYgWbYgAcAFji5ymrAL4ECCHHWSiI8bgBswqKFmUZkAXmQBtAORlKbgDTI3HCDcAXREHQxA6VgIwAE9lFAARMzhLa1t7J2RY%20KwYE2TUmzsMKJhuEAQwYBxkZWAEAGsACiw%20ACsadChsEABKTvqGgB4unt8k8ysi%20xcQXgEoIIA%20AjKKqpq6xpH05AgAD0gQUQcGiBjctEwcX2mHA6OT5AAlCDEcCxiAQSgoOBidnYlksWu1OtcQL5lOkZGgYf00IMRhDbjDZvNoMtVuVKtVcFthgAVPaHCDHU7nS6jHAg1odK7dG61GGZUyTNLFXr4JTISRgbhQfEwgB0klE3CQTSakgwUPSXMcS2QTUIwmEwo1Mu8POELmhdiCNDpevSQR5Ol6vjwOlCiO21MhyEJS16un04WMkDoDsyqpIni4bnIwDA2AwPh5ARoAGZo9rhGIJFJYW4AOLPADCEeEag0NDcAAYi24CDooh6wLypKlMgSml7rBCuQB6ZvEVBIh2%20ABEAe7yAAPshuwFuysK1WMKkAEy1wb1qSNxmO9y5kCBIIttsd%200o4driBjgxGSsy1LRueNBfevfuOB8BDBLck%20KVCCiPa-LBQIA)

You can find more advanced `pick` typings in my [article](https://catchts.com/deep-pick) and other answers:
[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126879/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object-with-related-type#answer-69129328) , [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668055/eliminate-nevers-to-make-union-possible/68672512?noredirect=1#comment121362429_68672512), [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67242871/declare-a-type-that-allows-all-parts-of-all-levels-of-another-type#answer-67247652)

**UPDATE**

There is a problem with `props` argument in this code:

```js
function pick<T extends keyof Person>(obj: Person, props: PropsOrDefault<T> = defaultProps): PickedPropOrDefault<PropsOrDefault<T>> {
    return props.reduce((res, prop) => {
        return {
            ...res,
            [prop]: obj[prop]
        }
    }, {});
}
```

`PropsOrDefault` might be equal to this type:`type UnsafeReduceUnion = DefaultProps | ReadonlyArray<'phone' | 'address'>` 
You probably have noticed, that these arrays in the union are completely different. They have nothing in common.

If you will  to call `reduce`:

```js
declare var unsafe:UnsafeReduceUnion;

unsafe.reduce()
```

you will get an error, because `reduce` is `not callable`

Comment: It seems to work properly and makes sense...! I was mostly concentrated on achieving this with a single function type definition and completely skipped the function overloading part. Thanks!

Comment: It happens to me all the time. You are welcome!

Comment: Hey, after getting triggered by your answer, I took a better look at conditional types and tried this approach (just for educational reasons, since it is getting quite complicated). I managed to make the function signature work properly, but `reduce` seems to be causing problems... Can you take a look at the updated playground in the original question update?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that? [Updated TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3ESXI9aQK7kBG0ViWRwAJqKgQMGGnQYgWbYgAcAFji5ymrAL4ECCHHWSiI8bgBswqKFmUzkAJQhicFgJ4BBKFDjuAPADWEO5YMGiYOAB8yAC8yADaAORklEkANMhJHBBJALoiGMiGIHSs%20jDcIAhgwDjIysAIgf4AKsgQAB6QIKJFwaHh6FDYIFEAFFh8AFY0w6OZyrb2NM6uIB7evgGtMfHjpuZWNnZFcEVrom5ePn5tUQCUD3NNLfM4mbv4wkrIkmDcKC4JanAB0klE3CQ43Gkgwi2WDziMUIwmEcISIOUBXiU2mmOWeSEaOI-0BuDhxOIOkyeB0hTQr387xA6V2D10%20hKxkgdBZc0iuHiqJIqS4SXIwDA2AwGV%20ORoAGZFel5eI4Q4kgBxRwAYTlwjUGhoSQADOakgQdKwgA).

```
const defaultProps: ReadonlyArray<keyof Person> = ['name', 'age'] as const;

function pick<T extends keyof Person>(obj: Person, props: ReadonlyArray<T> = (defaultProps as ReadonlyArray<T>)): Pick<Person, T> {
```

**UPDATED:**

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3ESXI9aQK7kBG0ViWRwAJqKgQMGGnQYgWbYgAcAFji5ymrAL4ECCHHWSiI8bgBswqKFmUzkAJQhicFgJ4BBKFDjuAPADWEO5YMGiYOAB8yAC8yADaAORklEkANMhJHBBJALqs%20jDcIAhgwDjIysAIgf4AKsgQAB6QIKIYyMGh4ehQ2LjxKRS5yAA%20WTlJUQAUWHwAVjR9A5nKtvY0zq4gHt6%20AfUx8TOm5lY2dp1wnduibl4%20fg1RAJSvyzV1KziZR-jCJTISRgbhQXDrK4AOkkom4SBmM0kGDWG1ecRihGEwmRCUhyjycWQ8wWeI2BSBOIgoPBwKkQhIOkyeB0Ik6qC%20-h%20IHSR1eun0hhAxkgdG5y0ig3wQNSXCS5GAYGwGAyQJyNAAzBr0mrxMiHEkAOKOADCquEag0NCSAAY7UkCDpCkKRVIwABGInVWozUXWSWZZKyjKTTj5fkGIxgZB%20gBMXq%20vrd3IjQA).

Comment: I do not think this is the right answer because this way `defaultProps` are typed as all the keys of Person. If you make a test call `const test1 = pick(testPerson, ['name']);` `test1` is properly typed as `Pick<Person, "name">`. However, if you make the call `const test2 = pick(testPerson)` then `test2` is typed `Pick<Person, keyof Person>` while it should be typed as `Pick<Person, "name" | "age">` UpdatedTs: https://shorturl.at/dhiqI

Comment: Then we could set default types as well. Updated TS Playground in the answer.