# How to use the values of a nested object as a TypeScript type

Tags: typescript

### The question

Having the following object:

```js
const categories = {
  foo1: {
    bar1: "baz1"
  },
  foo2: {
    bar2: "baz2"
  }
} as const
```

How could I dynamically use `baz1` and `baz2` as the accepted values, as so:

```
type Item = {
  categories: Array<'baz1' | 'baz2'>
}
```

### What I've done

I've managed to put together the following utils:

```
type Join<K, P> = K extends string | number
    ? P extends string | number
        ? `${K}${'' extends P ? '' : '.'}${P}`
        : never
    : never

type Prev = [never, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...0[]]

type Leaves<T, D extends number = 10> = [D] extends [never]
    ? never
    : T extends object
    ? { [K in keyof T]-?: Join<K, Leaves<T[K], Prev[D]>> }[keyof T]
    : ''
```

Which allow me to do the following:

```
type CategoryKeys = Leaves<typeof categories> // `foo1.bar1`, `foo2.bar2`
```

### The problem

But the problem is that this won't work:

```
type CategoryValues = typeof categories[CategoryKeys] // ❌
// or
type CategoryValues = typeof categories['foo1.bar1'] // ❌
```

Because what would actually work, afaik, is:

```
type CategoryValues = typeof categories['foo1']['bar1'] // `baz1`
```

---

Thank you!

Comment: Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67242871/declare-a-type-that-allows-all-parts-of-all-levels-of-another-type#answer-67247652_)

Comment: See [this](https://tsplay.dev/NarGnm) playground. You can check my [article](https://catchts.com/deep-pick) and if you are interested in generating digit range, you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/range-numbers) or [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089549/typescript-template-literal-type-how-to-infer-numeric-type#answer-69090186)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just a union of all existed values, you can check this:

```js
const categories = {
    foo1: {
        bar1: "baz1"
    },
    foo2: {
        bar2: "baz2"
    }
} as const

type Primitives = string | number | symbol;

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type ValuesUnion<T, Cache = T> =
    T extends Primitives ? T : Values<{
        [P in keyof T]:
        | Cache | T[P]
        | ValuesUnion<T[P], Cache | T[P]>
    }>

type Result = ValuesUnion<typeof categories>
```

[Playground](https://https:/tsplay.dev/WzP21N)