# Nested keys generics

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I want to create a type that will have a generic type and 2 properties that will split nested paths of specified type.

```
export type RecursiveKeyOf<TObj extends object> = {
    [TKey in keyof TObj & (string | number)]: TObj[TKey] extends any[]
    ? `${TKey}`
    : TObj[TKey] extends object
    ? `${TKey}` | `${TKey}.${RecursiveKeyOf<TObj[TKey]>}`
    : `${TKey}`;
}[keyof TObj & (string | number)];

type SubRecursiveKeys<RK extends string, PFX extends RK> = RK extends `${PFX}.${infer SubKey}` ? SubKey : never;

const a = {
    level1: {
        level2: {
            level3: {
                level4: {
                    level5: 'test'
                }
            }
        }

    }
}


type SubKeys = SubRecursiveKeys<RecursiveKeyOf<typeof a>, 'level1.level2'> // ok

// error here - does not satisfy the constraint 
type ShortHandKeyMapper<F extends object, Base extends RecursiveKeyOf<F> = RecursiveKeyOf<F>> = {
    control: Base                              // error here - does not satisfy the constraint 
    value: SubRecursiveKeys<RecursiveKeyOf<F>, Base>
}

const denyMapper: ShortHandKeyMapper<typeof a> = {
    control: 'level1.level2.level3',
    value: 'level2' // shouldnt allow this
}

const okMapper: ShortHandKeyMapper<typeof a> = {
    control: 'level1.level2.level3',
    value: 'level4' // should allow this or 'level4.level5'
}
```

`ShortHandKeyMapper` is the type that will have `control` as the prefix part of a nested path and `value` as the remaining part.

I get `does not satisfy the constraint` that makes no sense.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5&ssl=41&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKwDGBXKBnASwDdgBpYRAeQDMAeAFUoCMArOUGYAOwBM84IrLDAB8cALxwA3gCg48uAG165RHAJc4AawoRqcRqzgAyOAAo8MKBoDmcAD5wu2ALZNgUAJQBdAFwHmFmVVb3YQTl5+AEMuREVvOQUkgH44AAMAEikVCgBfNMSk+X9DIJzEUI5uPgEhTBhCotTM7NV8h3Ss8tyAOiyMHHxiMgoaBkDgim8RfMak-xbutIBuGVzFHUQ9AKNTCytbDuc3Dx9VmSQUOABlbCYB3EISVTxaNFIwiJrLay4bABo4AAFABiAA1PtV+O8xJJ3pDIp0pKCwb0shpqB4bnc2mk4KlbkxVHB-FxgCQoOdMBAuJY4FEJLIkgAbcnAZkARn8TKK8lZJGZACZuXNeXB+eyAMwisWy8Vs5kAFhlctVEuZAFZ-AByTiWbWi1W5Q1FY2ys0KRrG40yC7IVCEl4SbH3LCPYYvN5uobPUZ0S7AbZRESA7Xqjk9dWC7ViAD0sYEWltqpTqbT6YzcHj7CgUGgcAAFh5UABaOA8CDAfhcCDwPBRGAEPDUNQwItwam0qxRDTwO1Xa4F6AwAASMR4qgAslEwCgoLQQQiaoIWMJAQAhKJ4VBVREPH0jKh0EGw9Dep6HsYn088+SdqwQZn+TfbzPp7MePNQQvFuBlitVk4tZwPWjbNq27adj8PZcH2SREFEzLYMA-iEvuF6euhHp+guIZwC+wAiGstpQfAPDcIg06zh4qFDrAY68FOM5zrQAZBjejT3nmT5wGGCoRlGkYKpK2r-I0CFIShvFRtqWYJngQ7YMyPCwfSzLMhAADuCAFk2xEyKRiZUXOtHDgxE4UMZHisfa7HOreHY0g+PF8QKAkKoKQkCiJYnwYhyE6uqiqydmCkQEpPBqRp2ltk2Ajfq57KKl57IagauRAA)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `RecursiveKeyOf`, it is written with mistakes. Using (string | number) here `TKey in keyof TObj & (string | number)` is not correct.

Please consider this example:

```js
type RecursiveKeyOf<T, Cache extends string = ''> =
    T extends PropertyKey ? Cache : {
        [P in keyof T]:
        P extends string
        ? Cache extends ''
        ? RecursiveKeyOf<T[P], `${P}`>
        : Cache | RecursiveKeyOf<T[P], `${Cache}.${P}`>
        : never
    }[keyof T]

type SubRecursiveKeys<RK extends string, PFX extends RK> = RK extends `${PFX}.${infer SubKey}` ? SubKey : never;

const a = {
    level1: {
        level2: {
            level3: {
                level4: {
                    level5: 'test'
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

const infered = <Obj extends object,>(obj: Obj) =>
    <Control extends RecursiveKeyOf<Obj>>(
        control: Control,
        value: SubRecursiveKeys<RecursiveKeyOf<Obj>, Control>
    ) => ({
        control,
        value
    })

const curry = infered(a)

const _ = curry('level1.level2.level3', 'level4') // ok
const __ = curry('level1.level2.level3', 'level4.level5') // ok
const ___ = curry('level1.level2.level3', 'level5') // expected error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJAR5m)

Please see related answers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67242871/declare-a-type-that-allows-all-parts-of-all-levels-of-another-type#answer-67247652) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668055/eliminate-nevers-to-make-union-possible/68672512?noredirect=1#comment121362429_68672512) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126879/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object-with-related-type#answer-69129328)

Also, you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/deep-pick)

In order to have a guarantee that you object is valid, you need to infer `control` and then TS will be able to compute `value`.

If you don't need/want to use a function for inference, you can generate all allowed states of an object. See this:

```js
type RecursiveKeyOf<T, Cache extends string = ''> =
    T extends PropertyKey ? Cache : {
        [P in keyof T]:
        P extends string
        ? Cache extends ''
        ? RecursiveKeyOf<T[P], `${P}`>
        : Cache | RecursiveKeyOf<T[P], `${Cache}.${P}`>
        : never
    }[keyof T]

type SubRecursiveKeys<RK extends string, PFX extends RK> = RK extends `${PFX}.${infer SubKey}` ? SubKey : never;

const a = {
    level1: {
        level2: {
            level3: {
                level4: {
                    level5: 'test'
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type ValidState<Obj> = Values<{
    [Prop in RecursiveKeyOf<Obj>]: {
        control: Prop,
        value: SubRecursiveKeys<RecursiveKeyOf<Obj>, Prop>
    }
}>

type Result = ValidState<typeof a>

// expected error
const denyMapper: Result = {
    control: 'level1.level2.level3',
    value: 'level2' // shouldnt allow this
}

// ok
const okMapper: Result = {
    control: 'level1.level2.level3',
    value: 'level4' // should allow this or 'level4.level5'
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w25EzW)

type `Result` is just a union of all allowed states